# Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, undefined-behavior

Ever since I realized many years ago, that this doesn't produce an error by default (in GCC at least), I've always wondered why?

I understand that you can issue compiler flags to produce a warning, but shouldn't it always be an error? Why does it make sense for a non-void function not returning a value to be valid?

An example as requested in the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int stringSize()
{
}

int main()
{
    char cstring[5];
    printf( "the last char is: %c\n", cstring[stringSize()-1] ); 
    return 0;
}
```

...compiles.

Comment: Alternatively, I treat all warnings however trivial like errors, and I activate all the warnings I can (with local deactivation if necessary... but then it's clear in the code why).

Comment: `-Werror=return-type` will treat just that warning as an error. I just ignored the warning and the couple of minutes of frustration tracking down an invalid `this` pointer lead me here and to this conclusion.

Comment: This is made worse by the fact that flowing off the end of an `std::optional` function without returning returns a "true" optional

Comment: @Rufus It doesn't have to. That was just what happened to happen on your machine / compiler / OS / lunar cycle. Whatever junk code the compiler generated because of the undefined behaviour just happened to just about look like a 'true' optional, whatever that is.

Comment: С++2003, 6.6.3 2:
"Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function"

Answer (score 165, accepted):

C99 and C++ standards require non-`void` functions to return a value, except `main`. The missing return statement in `main` will be defined (to return `0`).  In C++ it's undefined behaviour if execution actually reaches the end of a non-`void` function other than `main`, while in C it's only UB if the caller *uses* the return value.

This means functions can look like they might reach the end without returning a value, but actually can't reach the closing `}`.  [John Kugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no/1610111#1610111) shows some examples, like a noreturn function called from one side of an `if`.  It's only undefined behaviour if execution actually does get to the end without reaching a `return` earlier.  The rationale includes that checking if every real code path returns a value is quite difficult (without knowing which functions never return), so it's not illegal to *compile* a function like your example, only to actually call it like your `main` does.

As an extension, at least one compiler (MSVC) [allows a return value to be set with inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802683/does-asm-return-the-value-of-eax), but most others still require a return statement in functions that use inline `asm`.

From [C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/1505939) draft:

§ 6.6.3/2

> Flowing off the end of a function [...] results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

§ 3.6.1/5

> If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return`  statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Note that the behaviour described in C++ 6.6.3/2 is not the same in C.

---

gcc will give you a warning if you call it with -Wreturn-type option.

> **-Wreturn-type** Warn whenever a function is defined with a return-type that
> defaults to int. Also warn about any
> return statement with no return-value
> in a function whose return-type is not
> void (falling off the end of the
> function body is considered returning
> without a value), and about a return
> statement with an expression in a
> function whose return-type is void.
>
> This warning is enabled by **-Wall**.

---

Just as a curiosity, look what this code does:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
   int a = 5;
   int b = a + 1;
}

int main() { std::cout << foo() << std::endl; } // may print 6
```

This code has formally undefined behaviour, and in practice it's [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and [architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) dependent. On one particular system, with one particular compiler, the return value is the result of last expression evaluation, stored in the `eax` register of that system's processor, if you disable optimization.

This seems to be a consequence of GCC internals with optimization disabled, because in that case [it picks the return-value register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437831/return-value-from-writing-an-unused-parameter-when-falling-off-the-end-of-a-non) if it needs any to implement a statement.  With optimization enabled in C++ mode, GCC and clang assume this path of execution is unreachable because it contains undefined behaviour.  They don't even emit a `ret` instruction, so execution falls into the next function in the .text section.  Of course undefined behaviour means that anything could happen.

Comment: I'm picking this one because I feel like it's the most concise.

Comment: I'd be wary of calling undefined behaviour "allowed", though admittedly I'd also be wrong to call it "prohibited". Not being an error and not requiring a diagnostic are not quite the same as "allowed". At the very least, your answer reads a bit like you're saying it's OK to do, which largely it is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hope it is less misleading now.

Comment: I think it's better, though still tends towards suggesting to language newcomers that you will end up with a program whose semantics are defined if you omit a `return` statement in a function that is supposed to return a value. True, C++ "doesn't require" the `return` statement in that it "doesn't require" erroring about its omission, but C++ _does_ require it for your program to have well-defined semantics... which is what we strive for.

Comment: I guess require is a tricky word... some people like to ski off-piste

Comment: @Catskul, why do you buy that argument? Wouldn't it be feasible, if not trivially easy, to identify exit points of a function and make sure they all return a value (and a value of the declared return type)?

Comment: @BlueBomber I think you can easily cause the number of code paths in a function to explode such that it would be prohibitive to traverse them all.

Comment: @Catskul, yes and no. Statically typed and/or compiled languages do lots of things that you would probably consider "prohibitively expensive", but because they only do it once, at compile time, they have negligible expense. Even having said that, I don't see why identifying exit points of a function needs to be super-linear: You just traverse the AST of the function and look for return or exit calls. That's linear time, which is decidedly efficient.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If a function with a return value sometimes returns immediately with a value and sometimes calls another function which always exits via `throw` or `longjmp`, should the compiler require an unreachable `return` following the call to the non-returning function?  The case where it isn't needed aren't very common, and a requirement to include it even in such cases probably wouldn't have been onerous, but the decision not to require it is reasonable.

Comment: @supercat: A super-intelligent compiler will not warn or error in such a case, but -- again -- this is essentially incalculable for the general case, so you're stuck with a general rule of thumb. If you know, though, that your end-of-function will never be reached, then you are so far from the semantics of traditional function handling that, yes, you can go ahead and do this and know that it's safe. Frankly, you're a layer below C++ at that point and, as such, all its guarantees are moot anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think there must be return statement exist if return type is not void. What is the reason that C (and Hence C++) left it undefined? any idea??? Thanks

Comment: @meet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9936084/560648 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1610454/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, it depends in which context the behavior is undefined. For instance, uninitialized dynamically allocated memory may hold unpredictable value. But it is allowed, of course. In this case I agree with you, but I also buy the path checking argument.

Comment: @user12918723509187: UB is UB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: By definition, yes. But it isn't the philosophy of C++ to be the guardian of everything that could possibly go wrong. As long as it is documented, it is the programmer's job to take care of not falling into the trap.

Comment: @user12918723509187: Exactly.

Comment: If a function `int foo(int x)`, among its other duties, returns the lowest prime factor of `x` if `x` is composite, and falls through if it's prime, and if the function is called by some functions which pass composite numbers and use the return value, and others that pass prime numbers but don't use the return value, behavior will be defined in all cases.  Having the function return a particular value in the prime-number case may necessitate including an otherwise-unnecessary "load" instruction.

Comment: @BlueBomber: Yes, it would be easy for compilers (and thus the language) to require that every possible path out of a non-void function returned a value.  The reason not to require that is that is may never be reached, e.g. in a function with a `while(1){}` loop and/or some `if() return x;` statements.  But proving that it's never reached could potentially require solving the halting problem, so instead in C++ you're allowed to write code that has a `}` without an obvious `return x;` before it, but it's UB if that's reached.  I made a major edit to this previously misleading answer.

Comment: @BlueBomber: [John Kugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610111/224132) on this question shows much better examples of functions that don't provably return a value, but which actually always do.  Java does what you suggest, sometimes requiring a useless `return 0` statement.

Answer (score 44):

gcc does not by default check that all code paths return a value because in general this cannot be done. It assumes you know what you are doing. Consider a common example using enumerations:

```
Color getColor(Suit suit) {
    switch (suit) {
        case HEARTS: case DIAMONDS: return RED;
        case SPADES: case CLUBS:    return BLACK;
    }

    // Error, no return?
}
```

You the programmer know that, barring a bug, this method always returns a color. gcc trusts that you know what you are doing so it doesn't force you to put a return at the bottom of the function.

javac, on the other hand, tries to verify that all code paths return a value and throws an error if it cannot prove that they all do. This error is mandated by the Java language specification. Note that sometimes it is wrong and you have to put in an unnecessary return statement.

```
char getChoice() {
    int ch = read();

    if (ch == -1 || ch == 'q') {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        return (char) ch;
    }

    // Cannot reach here, but still an error.
}
```

It's a philosophical difference. C and C++ are more permissive and trusting languages than Java or C# and so some errors in the newer languages are warnings in C/C++ and some warnings are ignored or off by default.

Comment: If javac actually checks code-paths wouldn't it see that you could never reach that point?

Comment: In the first one it doesn't give you credit for covering all of the enum cases (you need a default case or a return after the switch), and in the second one it doesn't know that `System.exit()` never returns.

Comment: It seems straightforward for javac (an otherwise powerful compiler) to know that `System.exit()` never returns. I looked it up (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29), and the docs just say it "never normally returns". I wonder what that means...

Comment: @Paul:  it means they didn't have a goodeditor.  All other languages say "never returns normally" -- i.e., "doesn't return using the normal return mechanism."

Comment: @JohnKugelman, I agree with your assessment of the first one, but I think the "problem" with the second example is more subtle: If the last statement in a sequence is an if/else (like it is here), all that is required for safety is to make sure the branches both return the same (and correct) type. If one branch returns the return value of a function call (as is the case for the if-branch here), that function doesn't have to be guaranteed to terminate for the program to pass compilation.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer a compiler that at least warned if it encountered that first example, because the correctness of the logic would break if anyone added a new value to the enum. I'd want a default case that complained loudly and/or crashed (probably using an assertion).

Comment: And then had a way to shut the compiler up if you knew what you were doing. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3378560/5391501 for GCC and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7159348/5391501 for MSVC have the way to do this for those compilers.

Comment: The "philosophical difference" is between memory-safe languages like Java, and languages that have undefined behaviour like C++.  Languages designed to be sandboxable mustn't allow nasal demons.  (Or corrupting things that would require callers to spend extra code checking for.)

Answer (score 16):

You mean, why flowing off the end of a value-returning function (i.e. exiting without an explicit `return`) is not an error?

Firstly, in C whether a function returns something meaningful or not is only critical when the executing code actually *uses* the returned value. Maybe the language didn't want to force you to return anything when you know that you are not going to use it anyway most of the time.

Secondly, apparently the language specification did not want to force the compiler authors to detect and verify all possible control paths for the presence of an explicit `return` (although in many cases this is not that difficult to do). Also, some control paths might lead into to *non-returning functions* - the trait that is generally non known to the compiler. Such paths can become a source of annoying false positives.

Note also, that C and C++ differ in their definitions of the behavior in this case. In C++ just flowing off the end of a value returning function is always undefined behavior (regardless of whether the function's result is used by the calling code). In C this causes undefined behavior only if the calling code tries to use the returned value.

Comment: +1 but can't C++ omit `return` statements from the end of `main()`?

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Yes, `main` is special in that regard.

Answer (score 7):

C and C++ have different rules.

---

The language rule in C is that if the closing `}` of a function that returns a non-`void` value is reached *and* the caller attempts to use that value, the behavior is undefined. Just falling off the end of the function has well defined behavior as long as the caller doesn't use the value.

It would be possible to require all possible control paths to execute a `return` statement before leaving the function, but C traditionally has not required compilers to do that kind of code analysis. (Many compilers will do that analysis anyway and issue a warning if appropriate.)

The main reason for allowing falling off the end of a non-`void` function is historical. K&R C (the version described in the 1978 first edition of Kernighan and Ritchie's book, before the 1989 ANSI and 1990 ISO C standard) did not have the `void` keyword or type. And prior to the 1999 ISO C standard, C had the "implicit `int`" rule, meaning that you could declare or define a function without an explicit return type and it would return an `int` result.

In K&R C, if you wanted a function that didn't return a result, you would define it without an explicit return type and simply not return a value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

do_something() {
    printf("Not returning a value\n");
}

int main() {
    do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

The function would actually return some garbage `int` value which the caller would quietly ignore.

In modern C, you would write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_something(void) {
    printf("Not returning a value\n");
}

int main(void) {
    do_something();
}
```

which guarantees that the caller *can't* try to use the returned value. As of C89/C90, the language still supported the old style to avoid breaking existing code. When the implicit `int` rule was dropped in C99, the requirements on non-`void` functions failing to return a value were not changed (and most C99 and later compilers still support the implicit `int` rule by default, probably with a warning, so old K&R C code can still be compiled).

---

In C++, flowing off the end of a function other than a constructor, a destructor, a `void` function, or `main` results in undefined behavior, regardless of what the caller tries to do with the result.

Answer (score 5):

It is legal under C/C++ to not return from a function that claims to return something.  There are a number of use cases, such as calling `exit(-1)`, or a function that calls it or throws an exception.

The compiler is not going to reject legal C++ even if it leads to UB if you are asking it not to.  In particular, you are asking for *no warnings* to be generated.  (Gcc still turns on some by default, but when added those seem to align with new features not new warnings for old features)

Changing the default no-arg gcc to emit some warnings could be a breaking change for existing scripts or make systems.  Well designed ones either `-Wall` and deal with warnings, or toggle individual warnings.

Learning to use a C++ tool chain is a barrier to learning to be a C++ programmer, but C++ tool chains are typically written by and for experts.

Comment: Yeah, in my `Makefile` I have it running with `-Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`, but this was a one-off test script that I forgot to supply the arguments to.

Comment: As an example, making [`-Wduplicated-cond`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-10/msg00245.html) part of `-Wall` broke GCC bootstrap. Some warnings that seem appropriate in *most* code is not appropriate in all code. That's why they're not enabled by default.

Comment: your first sentence seems to be in contradiction with the quote in the accepted answer "Flowing off .... undefined behaviour...". Or is ub considered "legal"? Or do you mean that it is not UB unless the (not) returned value is actually used? I am worried about the C++ case btw

Comment: @tobi303 `int foo() { exit(-1); }` does not return `int` from a function that "claims to return int".  This is legal in C++.  Now, it doesn't return *anything*; the end of that function is never reached.  *Actually reaching* the end of `foo` would be undefined behavior.  Ignoring end of process cases, `int foo() { throw 3.14; }` also claims to return `int` but never does.

Comment: so i guess `void* foo(void* arg) { pthread_exit(NULL); }` is fine for the same reason (when its only usage is via `pthread_create(...,...,foo,...);`)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because of legacy code (C never required return statement so did C++). There is probably huge code base relying on that "feature". But at least there is `-Werror=return-type` 
flag on many compilers (including gcc and clang).

Comment: What do you mean "so did C++"?  This is something the two languages differ on.  In C++ it's UB right away, in C only if you use the return value.

Comment: At which point do we enter UB territory? Immediately after the call to that function?

Comment: Probably at the point where you fall off the end of a function returning std::string. Or some other non-trivial object.

Answer (score 1):

In some limited and rare cases, flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value could be useful. Like the following MSVC-specific code:

```
double pi()
{
    __asm fldpi
}
```

This function returns pi using x86 assembly. Unlike assembly in GCC, I know of no way to use `return` to do this without involving overhead in the result.

As far as I know, mainstream C++ compilers should emit at least warnings for apparently invalid code. If I make the body of `pi()` empty, GCC/Clang will report a warning, and MSVC will report an error.

People mentioned exceptions and `exit` in some answers. Those are not valid reasons. Either throwing an exception, or calling `exit`, will ***not*** make the function execution flow off the end. And the compilers know it: writing a throw statement or calling `exit` in the empty body of `pi()` will stop any warnings or errors from a compiler.

Comment: MSVC specifically supports falling off the end of a non-`void` function after inline asm leaves a value in the return-value register.  (x87 `st0` in this case, EAX for integer.  And maybe xmm0 in a calling convention that returns float/double in xmm0 instead of st0).  Defining this behaviour is specific to MSVC; not even clang with `-fasm-blocks` to support the same syntax makes this safe.  See [Does \_\_asm{}; return the value of eax?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36802683)

Answer (score -1):

Under what circumstances doesn't it produce an error?  If it declares a return type and doesn't return something, it sounds like an error to me.

The one exception I can think of is the `main()` function, which doesn't need a `return` statement at all (at least in C++; I don't have either of the C standards handy).  If there is no return, it will act as if `return 0;` is the last statement.

Comment: `main()` needs a `return` in C.

Comment: @Jefromi: The OP is asking about a non-void function without a `return <value>;` statement

Comment: main automatically returns 0 in C and C++. C89 needs an explicit return.

Comment: @Chris: in C99 there's an implicit `return 0;` at the end of `main()` (and `main()` only). But it's good style to add `return 0;` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting that warning because i forgot to add the statement
itr = itr ->currentNode;
basically missing that statement, function get into infinte loop and was never returning a value, That's the reason i was getting that warning during the compilation time

```
void* list_get(list* lst, int idx){

    node* itr = lst->head;
    
    if (idx >= lst->size){
        printf("list out of index");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(itr != NULL){
        if(itr->index == idx){
           return  itr->element;
        }
        itr = itr->currentNode;
     
    }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need to turn up your compiler warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -x c -
int main(void) { return; }
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
<stdin>: In function ‘main’:
<stdin>:1: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
<stdin>:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
$
```

Comment: Saying "turn on -Werror" is a non-answer. Clearly there is a difference in severity between issues classified as warnings and errors, and gcc treats this one as the less severe class.

Comment: @Jefromi - I said turn up warnings, and I'd say most of `-Wall` _should_ probably be errors anyway (especially this case). But the reason I had all three of those in there is because that's what I have `gcc` aliased to on my system.

Comment: @Jefromi: From the pure language point of view, there's no difference between warnings and errors. The compiler is only required to issue a "disgnostic message". There's no requirement to stop compilation or call something "an eror" and something else "a warning". One a diagnostic message is issued (or any kind), it is entirely up to you to make a decision.

Comment: @Chris - ah, okay. And I do tend to agree with you about the warnings really being errors. I myself compile with -Werror whenever I can - it's hard when you're not responsible for all the code, though.

Comment: Then again, the issue in question causes UB. Compilers are not required to catch UB at all.

Comment: @Andrey: I wasn't trying to speak from a pure language point of view. Compilers simply try to help you make that decision by choosing a single word based on how severe the issue probably is, and given that fact, we can ask the question of which word should be chosen for a particular issue, yes?

Comment: @Andrey - According to pmg's answer, it's a constraint violation, and must therefore issue a diagnostic.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the others probably did because the original question contains the quote "I understand that you can issue compiler flags to produce a warning, but shouldn't it always be an error?"

Comment: @Chris: I think people are expecting an answer of the form "gcc does what it does because ___" not "gcc can be made to do the right thing by ___". You've got my +1, though!

Comment: In 6.9.1/12 in n1256 it says "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I don't see it. It is a constraint violation to use an *explicit* empty `return;` in a non-void function, and it is a constraint violation to use `return <value>;` in a void function. But that's, I believe, not the topic. The OP, as I understood it, is about exiting a non-void function without a `return` (just allowing control to flow off the end of the function). It is not  a constraint violation, AFAIK. The standard just says it is always UB in C++ and sometimes UB in C.

Comment: @AndreyT - Ah. Before the code example, it said "return from non-void function without returning a value" which I took to mean an explicitly empty return.

Answer (score -4):

It is a constraint violation in c99, but not in c89.  Contrast:

c89:

> 3.6.6.4 The `return` statement
>
> Constraints
>
> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a
>   function whose return type is `void` .

c99:

> 6.8.6.4 The `return` statement
>
> Constraints
>
> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

Even in `--std=c99` mode, gcc will only throw a warning (although without needing to enable additional `-W` flags, as is required by default or in c89/90).

Edit to add that in c89, "reaching the `}` that terminates a function is equivalent to
executing a `return` statement without an expression" (3.6.6.4).  However, in c99 the behavior is undefined (6.9.1).

Comment: Note that this only covers explicit `return` statements. It doesn't cover falling off the end of a function without returning a value.

Comment: Note that C99 misses "reaching the } that terminates a function is equivalent to executing a return statement without an expression" so it's not made a constraint violation, and thus no diagnostic is required.