# Why do programs in C compile even when the return statement is missing?

Tags: c

I'm implementing some basic data structures in C and I found out that if I omit the return type from a function and call that function the compiler doesn't generate an error. I compiled with `cc file.c` and didn't use `-Wall` (so I missed the warning) but in other programming languages this is a serious error and the program won't compile.

Per Graham Borland's request, here's a simple example:

```
int test() 
{
  printf("Hi!");
}

int main() 
{ 
    test();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C is an old language and at the time it was introduced, returning integers was common enough to be the default return type of a function. People later started realizing that with more complicated return types, it was best to specify int to be sure you are not forgetting the return type, but in order to maintain backwards compatibility with old code, C could not remove this default behavior. Instead most compilers issue warnings.

If the function reaches the end without a return statement an undefined value is returned except in the `main` function, 0 is returned. This has the same reason as above.

```
/* implicit declaration of printf as: int printf(int); */

/* implicit int type */
main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
} /* implicit return 0; */
```

Comment: If you go back far enough (mid-80s or ealier), there wasn't a return type of `void`; so a function that didn't really return a value was still deemed to return an `int`.  But if you never used the value, it didn't matter if there wasn't a return at the end of the function.  Also note that in C89, the return value from main is undefined if you don't explicitly return a value.  It was only in C99 that it became defined that falling off the end of `main()` was equivalent to `return 0;`.  This was partly to follow the lead of C++98 which also defines that behaviour.

Comment: @Jonathan `void` was in PWB's C, which predated the 80's.

Comment: Maybe; but it wasn't in the C I learned on in 1983-4.  It arrived maybe 3 years later.  It depends on which compiler you were using.

Comment: nitpick, it is not the return value that is undefined, it is the behavior of the whole program that is undefined would it ever try to access the return value of the function. So if you'd do this (try to access the value) it could eat your hard disk or empty your bank account. And `main` is different (since C99) since it is an explicit exception that is specified in the standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The example in my answer is the exact test of the first program in the first edition of Kernighan and Ritchie's _The_ _C_ _Programming_ _Language_ (Published in 1978). Note the lack of a return statement and of a `#include <stdio.h>` (the latter is added in the second edition).

Comment: I'd not looked at my K&R1, but apart from the comments, I can readily believe it is what they used.  K&R didn't want to get involved in discussing the finer points of the return value from `main()` in the opening example.  Nevertheless, the value returned to the environment (shell calling the program) was not defined prior to compilation with C99 (so even in K&R2, the code is a little sloppy).  C coding standards are more stringent now than they were then.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah I forgot to say apart from the comments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also, they never return anything from `main` in any example throughout the whole book. They do mention that "a `return` statement with no expression causes control, but no useful value, to be returned to the caller," which I take to mean the return value is undefined but the behavior is well-defined.

Answer (score 7):

It's because in C, any variable / function is implicitly `int`.

This is the same reason that you can use `register` instead of `register int`, or `unsigned` instead of `unsigned int`, `auto` instead of `auto int`, and `static` instead of `static int`. I personally always explicitly qualify my variables with `int`, but whether you do or not is your option.

Comment: +1 for answering the question, although the example seems to suggest the OP wants something else.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of a function is optional and is considered "int" if not specified.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen the *why* addressed well in any of the answers so far. In C, it's perfectly legal for a function with a non-void return type to end without a return statement/value, *as long as the caller does not attempt to use the return value*. For instance (slightly nontrivial example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(int want_result)
{
    puts("hello");
    if (want_result) return 42;
}

int main()
{
    foo(0);
    printf("%d\n", foo(1));
}
```

This example is somewhat contrived, but it could actually become meaningful if the return type is a huge structure that would take non-trivial time to return.

Answer (score 0):

The function will not return 0 as the [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858391/why-do-programs-in-c-compile-even-when-the-return-statement-is-missing/10858444#10858444) says.

In fact, printf returns a value: the number of characters printed. In your case, printf, which is the last expression in your test function, will return 3. Thus the function *test* will return 3.

Comment: Surely it's undefined behavior...

Comment: Ah indeed, according this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2598133/1295368
The behavior I described is only for x86 platform but is clearly undefined.

Comment: C is not a expression language; functions *do not* return the value of the last expression.