# why does recursion function works in visual studio eventhough there is no return value

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int test(int numb) {
    if (numb == 0) return 0;
    test(numb - 1);
}

int main() {
    cout<<test(10);
}
```

so i was solving some algorithm questions. 
this code works in visual studio but not in other online shell.
what does test() function returning even though there is no return?
also

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int test(int numb) {
    if (numb == 0) return 0;
    cout<<test(numb - 1)<<endl;
}

int main() {
    cout<<test(10);
}

//result
0
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
1349009568
```

what does thoes number 1349009568 means??

Comment: You have *undefined behavior!* If you declare that a function should return a value, you should actually return a value.

Comment: Same goes for your main() function...

Comment: `main` is an allowed exception in C++. The standard says you are allowed to not return from `main`, and it will assume `return 0`

Comment: Also, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513935/1611055 has a more detailed (X86 specific) example why in certain conditions your code still might seem to work

Comment: I would say that `1349009568 == (int)&std::cout`.

Comment: You should also take a look at your compiler settings. The compiler can warn you about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has undefined behavior when it doesn't return anything.  The number 1349009568 is meaningless and probably random.  For me, it shows a 0, and has the same output as this version which will never return anything.

```c
int test(int numb) {
    if (false) return -1;
}
```