# How is this code working without returning the allocated pointer?

Tags: c, return, binary-tree, return-value

I am using this particular code for creating a binary tree and the code itself is working, but I seem to be lacking a critical concept to understand the code.

Node structure

```
typedef struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *left,*right;
}* Node;
```

The create function

```
Node create(){
    Node root = (Node) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x==-1) //create a null node
      return NULL;
    root->data=x;
    root->left = create();
    root->right = create();
}
```

The call for the function is

```
Node root=create();
```

In the create function there is no pointer to the root node being passed.
Within the function, a new node is being created, allocated memory and value of the node is assigned. But nowhere in the code is the pointer to the newly created node being passed or returned.

So how does this code work?

PS: The return type is Node. I think this is relevant but I have no idea as to why it is so. It might as well as be void as no value is returned.

Comment: This function is broken. It does not return a value as it should.

Comment: This code works? How are you using and testing the value of root after create call

Comment: A particular case of input. 0 1 2 -1 -1 3 4 -1 -1 5 -1 -1 6 -1 7 -1 8 9 10 -1 -1 11 -1 -1 12 -1 -1  I am using some other function to traverse and search, but those have the usual implementation

Comment: Again. this code is invoking *undefined behavior*, as the function of a non-void type does not return a value, yet the (non-existent) return value is assigned to something.

Comment: @Tyler I can access values within the tree like one would normally do. root->left->data gives me the expected value

Comment: @arsonist_50 you can only do that inside the function create

Comment: @EugeneSh. Exactly my point. How is this undefined behavior working? How is the return value being assigned? This is actually a very common implementation and I have seen a lot of websites using this.

Comment: It is not working. It is undefined. It can work *accidentally*. Give us please a link to this implementation...

Comment: It's UB, like @EugeneSh. says. It seems to work because you are unlucky and some stuff happens to line up, (today).  Having code like this 'work' is just about the worst outcome:(

Comment: 'This is actually a very common implementation and I have seen a lot of websites using this' - please link them, so that they can be avoided in future.  In fact, given your username, maybe you could burn down those sites for us:)

Comment: Ugh - in addition to the actual problems pointed out by everyone else, node creation and input should be separate operations.  Also, you're creating an unordered tree, which ... doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Sidenote: **Never ever** `typedef` a pointer. This will only cause trouble to the reader and makes good coding style problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, first off, there is a clear and straightforward bug in this function...

```
Node create(){
    Node root = (Node) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x==-1) //create a null node
      return NULL;
    root->data=x;
    root->left = create();
    root->right = create();
}
```

which the compiler *should have* pointed out to you:

```
test.c: In function ‘create’:
test.c:18:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

(If your compiler ate this code without any complaints at all, turn on warnings.  GCC in particular is way too permissive by default; if you're using GCC you should give it the `-Wall` option essentially *always*, and probably a bunch more `-Wsomething` options as well.)

The bug is simply that there's a missing last line:

```
return root;
```

Now, your actual question appears to be "I know there's a bug, but *why does it work anyway?*" and before I get into that, I need you to acknowledge that you understand that, if it works, it only works by accident, on the computer and with the compiler you happen to be using right now.  `create` has what we call "undefined behavior", which means that it's allowed to do *anything at all*, including appearing to work correctly, but also failing catastrophically.

There *is* a plausible explanation for why it works anyway: on many CPUs, the register used to return pointers is also a convenient scratch register, so when compiling the statement

```
root->right = create();
```

the compiler may place `root` in the return-value register in order to perform the memory access `root->right = ...`.  As there are no operations after that point, the generated machine code "falls off the end", without officially putting a return value in that register, but also not *removing* the local variable `root` from that register.  And so it appears to work.

---

Incidentally, there are a bunch more bugs in this function:

```
Node create(){
```

This has one mostly-harmless semantic error and one style error; it should be written

```
Node create(void)
{
```

In C, for historical reasons, you must write `(void)`, not `()`, to define a function that takes no arguments.  This is technically defining a function that takes an *unspecified number* of arguments, which means the compiler won't complain if you *call* `create` with arguments.

In C, unlike in some other languages you may be familiar with, the opening curly brace of a function definition should always be placed on its own line.

```
    Node root = (Node) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

In C (unlike C++), *do not* cast the return value of `malloc`.  It is not necessary, and if you don't, the compiler will remind you when you forgot to include `stdlib.h` and therefore your pointers are being truncated to the width of `int`.

```
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
```

[Never use `scanf` in production code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816).  Also, you are not checking for input errors.

```
    if(x==-1) //create a null node
      return NULL;
```

This leaks the just-allocated node when x is equal to -1.  This check should occur *before* the call to `malloc`.

Also, your indentation is inconsistent: you used 4-space indent for the first level and 2-space indent for the second level.  It doesn't matter what indentation style you use, but it *does* very much matter that you *pick a style and stick to it throughout your program*.

(And don't use tabs, because programs indented with tabs don't look the same for everybody.  8-space indent is fine, but they should actually be eight spaces.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Yes, I knew there was some kind of bug, but I still wanted to know why it was working. I didn't know about the -Wall flag. I will be careful about compiling such kind of code in future

Comment: @arsonist_50 You accepted the answer while I was editing it, please reread.

Comment: Why should the curly brace always be on its own line? I write it like this too but I always thought it's just a matter of style. The typedef of `Node` as a pointer bothers me much more than this.

Comment: @zwol i used to code previously in c++, so i guess i was still following some of its idiosyncrasies. Thanks for pointing it out. I used pass the parameter as void but I never understood why, so I stopped using it

Comment: @alain The _original_ reason was that in pre-C89 code you had to put it on its own line because the function parameter declarations went in between the (...) and the {.  Nowadays, it is just that putting the curly brace on the same line as the function head looks wrong to people familiar with the language, and is inconsistent with the way existing large codebases are formatted (and if you're working on C you're probably working on an existing large codebase).

Comment: @arsonist_50 Yeah, the (void) thing is an annoying vestige of the language as it was in the 1970s and 80s - yes, really, that long ago - but we're stuck with it.  In C++ it is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: @zwol seems like I should read some style guides for C, so that I can be aware of more bugs like that

Comment: Ah interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Nice answer.

Comment: You advised `Node create(void) { ... }`.  It's true that the external declaration ` `Node create();` declares a function that takes unspecified arguments, but are you sure that's true for definitions?  I would have thought that, even today, `Node create() { ... }` defined `create()` as accepting 0 arguments.

Comment: @SteveSummit Hmm, yes, you're right. C11 6.7.6.3p15 "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters."  However, experimenting with OP's code, I can add parameters to the recursive calls to `create` and no compiler I have convenient access to offers the slightest objection (see https://godbolt.org/g/ybEBPT)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are omitting the return statement at the end of `create`. C compilers are surprisingly permissive when it comes to this and will often compile just fine (though with warnings. You *do* have warnings enabled don't you!?).

Most likely the function is returning some arbitrary value sitting around in a register or in some stack frame, which luckily is the address of `root` so everything works as expected (see [Function with missing return value, behavior at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598084/function-with-missing-return-value-behavior-at-runtime/2598133#2598133)).

If you add `return root;` at the end of the function, it should continue working as before minus the undefined behavior.

Comment: I do have warnings enabled but I didn't get any during compiling the code. The code does work after adding return root; at the end.  So it is by luck that the code is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of create() function until it returns pointer which is pointing to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is the reason I commented, it should return pointer which is pointing to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Ah, OK, I have interpreted the answer in some other way. Anyway, this code is invoking UB.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you found a memory leak. The function is allocating resources on the heap but it doesn't pass control over to you or frees it.

Comment: But I am able to access it outside the create() function. Is that okay?

Comment: No. If you really can access the node structure like this, you are dealing with undefined behavior. And being lucky with the results, that's all

Comment: @savram: more like *un*lucky, because this code is fooling the OP into believing it's working properly, until the day it decides not to.