# Why the function get the same value getting the factorial?

Tags: c++

I made a recursive function in C++ to get a factorial.

```
unsigned factorial(unsigned n, int j = 1) {
 j++;
 if(j < n) {
     return j * factorial(n, j);
 }
 return n;
}
```

It works. However, if i remove the  `return n;` the function still working and i don't know why.

For simplicity, i got a control flow of factorial(5) with `return n;` removed, that is the following:

factorial (5,1) returns 2 * factorial (5,2)

factorial (5,2) returns 3 * factorial (5,3)

factorial (5,3) returns 3 * factorial (5,4)

And in the last, i.e factorial(5,4) since in the condition `if(j < n)`, j = 5 and n = 5, the condition not satisfies and therefore factorial(5,4) must return 1 by default. Thus, the total recursive function must return 2 * 3 * 4 * factorial(5,4) = 2 * 3 * 4 * 1 = 4! and not 5!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `j < n` ≠ `j <= n`

Comment: @Eljay yes, 5 < 5 is not true.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you removed `return n;`? Without the `return` your program has *undefined behaviour*, which means exactly what it says.

Comment: When i remove the ´return n;´ the program still working

Comment: But how is 'it's still working' incompatible with undefined behaviour? If the behaviour is not defined, then anything can happen, including still working.

Comment: There is no "return 1 by default" in C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function with missing return value, behavior at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598084/function-with-missing-return-value-behavior-at-runtime)

Comment: So, is error of Dev c++ compiler

Comment: No, C++ says that your program has *undefined behaviour*, Dev C++ could make this program do **anything** and Dev C++ would still be correct.

Comment: Your mistake is that you think a bad program must show an error when it runs. That's not true. Bad programs only have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: The program did not undefined behaviour, it behaved as if it had not removed return n. Executed in Dev C++

Comment: The C++ standard lays down behaviour for valid C++ programs. But for invalid C++ programs it just says the bahaviour is undefined, it doesn't say that they must not work. It's prefectly OK and normal for an invalid C++ program to work. It's not a compiler error if this happens, because *undefined behaviour* includes working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if i remove the `return n;` the function still working

Absolutely not. The code no longer works, and is in fact invalid (functions *must* return a value on all code paths, not doing so causes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)). The effect of undefined behaviour may, under certain circumstances, look as if the code “works”. But its behaviour is actually arbitrary, *and cannot be relied on*.

It’s just that the C++ compiler is not *required* to note this error, and some silently accept the code, even though it’s invalid.

That said, all modern compilers *will* warn you about this code. You should always compile with warnings enabled, and ideally with warnings treated as errors, to flag such wrong code. For example, in clang and GCC it’s best practice to specify the command line flags `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. I additionally strongly recommend specifying the flag `-Werror`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You know how to avoid this error in Dev C++?

Comment: Thanks, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers about UD are correct, only I want to add a note on why this may seem working. Functions in C++ might return a value in the RAX register. The previous calculation may have left RAX with the answer. So it seems that it works by optimization.

Ie I put the value to RBX and then I would do `mov rax, rbx` to implement the return, but by chance RAX already got that value.

Comment: This is indeed a likely explanation, but it doesn’t capture why it then fails arbitrarily. For instance, on godbolt with GCC 9.3 it works for some inputs and fails for others (well within range of the registers).

Answer (score 0):

Without the return statement the function has undefined behavior. For example  this program outputted nothing when I run it.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned factorial(unsigned n, int j = 1) {
 j++;
 if(j < n) {
     return j * factorial(n, j);
 }
// return n;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << factorial( 2, 1 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Moreover even with the return statement the function is invalid because for example for the first argument equal to 0 it returns 0 instead of 1.

The recursive function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long factorial( unsigned n ) 
{
    return n  < 2 ? 1 : n * factorial( n - 1 );
}

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 20;
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << factorial( i ) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 1
1: 1
2: 2
3: 6
4: 24
5: 120
6: 720
7: 5040
8: 40320
9: 362880
10: 3628800
11: 39916800
12: 479001600
13: 6227020800
14: 87178291200
15: 1307674368000
16: 20922789888000
17: 355687428096000
18: 6402373705728000
19: 121645100408832000
20: 2432902008176640000
```