# Implicit int return value of C function

Tags: c, function, legacy-code

I've googled and just can't seem to find the answer to this simple question.

Working on a legacy code base (ported to Linux recently, and slowly updating to a new compiler) and I see a lot of

```
int myfunction(...)
{
// no return...
}
```

I know the implicit return TYPE of a function is int, but what is the implicit return VALUE when no return is specified. I've tested and gotten 0, but that's only with gcc. Is this compiler specific or is it standard defined to 0?

EDIT: 12/2017
Adjusted accepted answer based upon it referencing a more recent version of the standard.

Comment: try to compile with -Wall -O3 and without -g . Try to see if return value is still 0 and if some warning exists

Comment: Try to compile with `-Wall -Werror` and see if it still compiles.

Comment: The accepted answer should be changed. Quoting 89 version of a standard is out of its place in 2016.

Comment: "implicit return type" was removed in C99

Comment: Really old school code tend to mix assembly and C code. In some cases, the assembly code would set the returning value. Be sure to check if any assembly code is present, either through an extern or _asm keyword.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Such a thing is possible, but only under the assumption that the return value of the function is never used. The C11 standard says in para 6.9.1:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
>   function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

(AFAIR previous version of the standard had similar wording)

So it would be a good idea to transform all the functions of that sort that you have to `void` functions, so no user of such a function could be tempted to use the return value.

Comment: Ok, are you saying that **as long as we don't read it**, behavior of the program is still OK?

Comment: Yes, the standard says that.

Comment: Well, the first answer by dmckee seems to contradict this.

Comment: @Pacerier, no I don't think it does, and ouah's answer also is saying the same thing.

Answer (score 25):

From the '89 standard as quoted in the new testament:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no expression. In either case, the return value is undefined.

That standard usually expresses the on-the-ground behavior of pre-existing implementations.

Comment: Do you mean that only the value is undefined, or that behavior of the program is undefined after that point?

Comment: The 89 standard doesn't specify. I would assume that actual compilers won't throw you any surprises if you don't attempt to use the return value. But no one is guaranteeing that.

Comment: Well, as Jens quotes it that standard seems to guarantee good behavior as long as you don't use the undefined return value.

Comment: @Pacerier it just means the value is undefined. The behavior of the program will still be defined, but any expression that uses that value will be undefined.

Comment: If a function is `int isempty(struct Node* top){
return !top;
}` What will it return? What **'!'** does while returning?

Answer (score 15):

The return statement is never mandatory at the end of a function, even if the function return type is not `void`. No diagnostic is required and it is not undefined behavior.

Example (defined behavior):

```
int foo(void)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

But reading the return value of `foo` is undefined behavior:

```
int bla = foo();  // undefined behavior
```

From the C Standard:

> ([C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), 6.9.1 on p.12) "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the         value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

The `main` function is an exception to this rule as if the `}` is reached in `main` it is equivalent as if there was a `return 0;` statement.

> ([C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 5.1.2.2.3 on p.13) ...reaching  the `}` that  terminates  the `main` function  returns  a  value  of  0.

Comment: *"and it is not undefined behavior"* unless the caller uses the return value.

Comment: @dmckee that's why I wrote: *"But reading the return value of foo is undefined behavior"*

Comment: @ouah Can we do this in cpp ?

Answer (score 9):

That's simply undefined behaviour; if you don't populate the return area (which for example is generally [eax/rax on x86 family processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)), it'll have the value last set up through some side-effect in your function.

See [Is a return statement mandatory for C++ functions that do not return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784075/is-a-return-statement-mandatory-for-c-functions-that-do-not-return-void) which is basically a duplicate of this question (except that it's tagged as C++).

Comment: Not quite, this is only UB if the return value is used, which probably is not the case here, please see my answer.

Comment: yes, it is not undefined behavior unless you read the return's value. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the `return` statements consistently do not return a value, the function is best converted to, and declared as, returning `void`:

```
void myfunction(...)
{
    ...
    return;
    ...
}
```

If there are some some `return expr;` and some `return;` statements in the function, then you need to decide which is the better behaviour, and make them consistent — either always return a value and leave the type as `int` or never return a value and change the type to `void`.

Note that you'll need to declare functions modified to return `void` (in a header, unless they are — or should be — `static` and hidden in a single source file) since the default return type (assumed return type) of `int` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

It may always be zero in that function, but on most architectures (certainly x86) the return statement moves the contents of a specific register to a specific place on the stack which the caller will retrieve and use as its return function.

The return statement will place the variable passed to it in that location so that it'll be a different value. My experience with not placing a specific return statement is that its fairly random what gets returned and you can't rely on it being the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain that it is undefined behaviour for a function whose return type is not `void` to omit a `return` statement. In C99 there is an exception for `main`, where if the `return` statement is omitted, it is assumed to return 0 implicitly, but this doesn't apply to any other function.

It may work on a specific platform/compiler combination but you should never rely on such specifics. Using any kind of undefined behaviour in your code makes it unportable. It is common to see undefined behaviour in legacy code though.