# Arduino - waiting on function causes a number pile-up

Tags: function, floating-point, arduino, return

I have a function `filledFunction()` that returns a float `filled`:

```
float filledFunction(){
    if (FreqMeasure.available()) {
        sum = sum + FreqMeasure.read();
        count = count + 1;
        if (count > 30) {
            frequency = FreqMeasure.countToFrequency(sum / count);
            a = frequency * x;
            b = exp (a);
            c = w * b;
            d = frequency * z;
            e = exp (d);
            f = y * e;
            float filled = c + f;
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
            return filled;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call this function with

```
while (1){
    fillLevel = filledFunction();
    int tofill = 500 - fillLevel;
    Serial.print("fillLevel:    ");
    Serial.println(fillLevel);
    Serial.print("tofill:       ");
    Serial.println(tofill);
```

The serial monitor should output two numbers that add up to 500 named `fillLevel` and `tofill`. Instead I get a repeating sequence of similar values:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxIoH.png

The First two values are correct (410.93 + 89 = 500), but the following 60ish values are unknown to me, and do not belong there.

I am using an arduino nano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filledFunction()` function only returns a value if `FreqMeasure.available()` returns `true` AND `count > 30`. As stated in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079089/implicit-int-return-value-of-c-function) the C89, C99 and C11 standards all say that the default return value of a function is undefined (that is if the function completes without executing a `return` statement). Which really means that anything could happen, such as outputting arbitrary numbers.

In addition, the output that you're seeing starts off 'correct' with one of the numbers subtracted from `500`, even when they have weird values such as `11699.00` and `-11199` (which equals `500 - 11699.00`). However, lower down in the output this seems to break down and the reason is that on Arduino Nano an `int` can only hold numbers up to `32767` and therefore the result of the subtraction is too big and 'overflows' to be a large negative number.

Fixing the `filledFunction()` function to explicitly return a value even if `FreqMeasure.available()` is `false` or `count <= 30` and ensuring that it can't return a number greater than `500` will likely solve these issues.

Comment: I see, I'll stick an else statement to see if that solves it. And I did notice the the values reaching the data types limit, I just don't know what the value is or why it is changing as much as it is... Thanks anyway.