# Xcode compilation error "Control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: xcode, clang, compiler-warnings

I have an error in a script I am writing, the error is:

> Control reaches end of non-void function

This is my code:

```
-(BOOL) hasInternet {
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.co.uk"];
    NetworkStatus internetStats = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (internetStats == NotReachable){
        UIAlertView *alertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet" message:@"is DOWN" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Turn on your Internet" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
        [alertOne show];
    }
}
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You do not return anything from a function that expects return value - exactly what compiler error tells you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is designed to return a boolean value using a return statement, for example `return YES;`.

Since you haven't implemented such thing, the method won't compile successfully. If you want to return a `BOOL` you can add a return statement. If you don't want to return a `BOOL` just change the method initialization:

```
    -(void) hasInternet {

       Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.co.uk"];
       NetworkStatus internetStats = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

      if (internetStats == NotReachable){
         UIAlertView *alertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet" message:@"is DOWN" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Turn on your Internet" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
         [alertOne show];
      }

    }
```

Comment: I'm being pedantic, but it's not that the method "won't work". The value returned will [just be undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079089/implicit-int-return-value-of-c-function) (though you'll most likely end up returning `0` implicitly).

Comment: yeah, but since it's a syntax error, it won't even compile.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help, Fixed following "return false"

Comment: @returnfalse you're right. don't know why I assumed it would be a warning (not a _syntax_ error though ;) ).