# Omitting "return" statement in a function recursively calling itself

Tags: c, recursion

```c
typedef struct s_node {
    int val;
    struct s_node *left_child;
    struct s_node *right_child;
} NODE;

NODE *get_node_by_val(NODE *root, int searched_val) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        if (root->val == searched_val)
            return root;
        else if (root->val > searched_val)
            get_node_by_val(root->left_child, searched_val); /**/
        else if (root->val < searched_val)
            get_node_by_val(root->right_child, searched_val); /**/
    } else
        return root;
}
```

Today we were talking about binary search trees. `get_node_by_val` above searches for a `NODE` in such a tree with its `val` matching the given `searched_val`. Recursively.

The point of contention is lines 12 and 14, marked with the `/**/`.

At first sight, or to me at least it seems, they both should have been preceded by `return` statements. Without the `return` statement, my guess is that the subtree is indeed searched, but nothing is done with the value it returns. At some point, some call to `get_node_by_val` will return (either `NULL` or a pointer to the matching node), and this value will be passed to the caller, but this may happen levels of recursion down, in which the caller would have to pass this value back to its caller, and so on, all the way up to the first caller. But without the `return` statement, only the caller 'immediately above' the one that returns gets that information.

Or so this would be my guess.

The problem is that this code WORKED (this happened earlier today in class, haven't tried it once again at home).

Why? How?

My uneducated guess is as follows: the deepest recursive call, the one that returns, puts its return value there on EAX. All of the calls above it don't return anything -- leaving EAX unchanged all the way up until the first caller returns (without returning anything).
At the end, the caller (the one that called `get_nove_by_val` the very first time) sees EAX still containing the value that that deepest call put there, and figures it may as well be the value that the first call may have returned, and so everything works.

Is that what happens?
Is this bad practice?

Comment: This looks like this would be undefined behavior. It just happens to work.

Comment: maybe it works for that compiler on that particular CPU... the alternative is adding `return` so it works everywhere. it's not only bad practice, it's undefined behaviour and a good compiler should warn you about that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079089/implicit-int-return-value-of-c-function

Comment: Nice. [modelnine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079181/9447177) to that question expains it in the same way I proposed.

Comment: Your function is a candidate for tail call elimination, if however you're compiling does that optimization.  That final recursion frame that actually returns a node might be a lot less deep on the stack then you'd guess... like, zero deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there are missing `return` keywords before the recursive calls to `get_node_by_val`. In both cases, the function exits without a `return` statement. Since it not a `void` function, this has undefined behavior.

The code behaves as expected because the register (or whatever other means appropriate for your system's ABI) used for the return value has been set in the recursive call (actually in the final recursive call) and happens do not modified by the caller until it returns to its own caller, which it does immediately. This behavior is not guaranteed and of course it is very bad practice to rely on it.

You should configure the compiler to issue useful warnings to avoid such silly mistakes: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, `clang -Weverything -Werror`...