# Is it necessary to put return in a void recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

*Feel free to make this post as a duplicate if the question asked already, I haven't found a post same as this*

As far as I know that there's no need to `return` in a `void` **function**, e.g:

```
void ex () {printf ("Hi\n");}
```

But, is it fine if there's no `return` in a `void` **recursion**? What I'm thinking is, the program will keep calling `func (num-1)` until it reaches `0` and it returns so it doesn't print `0` to the output, and I need `return` at the end of the function so after the recursion call is done, you go back to the previous `func ()` immediate caller.

Here's the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func (int num)
{
    if (!num) return;
    func (num-1);
    printf ("%d\n", num);

    return;             //Is it necessary to put return here?
}

int main ()
{
    func (10);

    return 0;
}
```

Output,

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Without the last `return`, it works just fine too, or am I missing something?

Comment: You need the `return` from the `if` as it is your stop condition. The second `return` you don't need as it does not affect the code. Without `return` the function ends and returns to the caller.

Comment: So the question is, whether it's required to use a `return` statement at the end of void function? No it's not; [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079089/implicit-int-return-value-of-c-function) more details on that.

Comment: @LastSecond959 There's no difference between recursive and non-recursive function in how their bodies are compiled. Returned type is what gives a function a distinction.

Comment: sometimes I work like a compiler and ignore comments specially with no coffee :P anyway, my comments was about removing all returns, its just as mentioned by other comments, its not needed.

Comment: @ROOT Ahaha, you're not the only one XD. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No `return` statement is required at all; the function can be structured as `{ if (num) { func(num-1); printf("%d\n", num); } }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function with return type `void` doesn't need an explicit `return`. Simply reaching the end of the function will properly return.

It is no different for void functions that are also recursive. The first `return` in your function is required because you want it to return before reaching the end of the function, but the second isn't required.

Comment: So you mean even it is a recursion, it will implicitly return to its immediate caller? While the `return` at `if` is needed to prevent infinite loop right? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . . .

Comment: Just to be clear, even the explicit `return` will only return to its immediate caller.

Comment: No `return` statement is required at all; the function can be structured as `{ if (num) { func(num-1); printf("%d\n", num); } }`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Please read again. I said it was required to return before reaching then end of the function.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Yeah, that's kinda my point. It stands on its own, but one expects comments to provide feedback about the answer on which they are posted. It's just so random and pointless. At best, it's redundant since I already mentioned that reaching the end of the function doesn't require a `return`. I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

A function returning void doesn't have to explicitly return. A program has 1 entry point, but might have multiple exit points. Consider the following example:

```
void print(int var)
{
    if (var)
       return; // first exit point
    /*
     *   do stuff
     */  
    // second exit point
}
```

It has 2 exit points. Second one is without a `return;`.

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func (int num)
{
    if (!num){ 
     printf("0\n");//print 0 before you stop
     return;
   }
    func (num-1);
    printf ("%d\n", num);


}

int main ()
{
    func (10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should OP try that? How exactly it solves their question?

Comment: he sayed that it doesn't print 0 to the output

Comment: @Escanor Thx for that but that isn't my question. I was asking is it fine to not put `return` at the end of void recursion.

Comment: s/(!num)/(num == -1)/ ?

Comment: @Escanor, I believe the OP was saying that it uses `return` because it's supposed to stop before printing `0`.