# How to structure linked list in C with pointers, keep getting error

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm quite new to C and am still coming to grips with a lot of the syntax and idiosyncrasies. I'm not exactly sure what needs changing in order to make my code work but am open to any ideas. I understand that I need to utilize pointers in order to make this work but I am still lost on the specific implementation. I keep getting an error that my myList function is undeclared but I feel like I have declared it already. Is there something I am missing about how C works? Any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
{
    
int data;
struct node* head;
struct node* next;  
 }node;


node*linkedList ();



int main ()
{
 
 
 struct linkedList* myList = (struct createList*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    myList.addNode(5);
    myList.addNode(10);
    myList.addNode(13);
    
    
 printf("%d\n", myList.search(10));
 
 printf("The linked list is this big: %d\n", myList.getSize);
 
 
 
    
    
    
}


node* linkedList ()
{   
    node* head;
    node* current;
    node*next;
    
    
    
    
     addNode (int x)
    {
        node keephead = head;
        current = head;
        
        while (current.next = NULL)
        {
        
        if (current.next = NULL)
        {
            
            current.next = node* newnode 
            newnode.data = x;
            newnode.next = NULL;
            newnode.head = keephead
        
        }
        
        if (head = NULL)
        {
            
            head = current;
        }
        
    }
        
    }
   
   int getSize ()
   {
     
     int counter = 0;
       
     node countNodes = head;
        
     while (countNodes.next != NULL)
     {
         countNodes = countNodes.next;
         counter++;

         
     }
       
       return counter;
   }
   
   int search(int value)
   {
       int index = 0;
      node searchNode = head;
      
      while(searchNode.next!= NULL)
      {
            searchNode = searchNode.next;
            index++;
        
         
         
         if (node.value = data)
         {
             break;
            
         }
          
          else {
              
              index = -1;
          }
              
      }
       
       return index;
   }
   
   
   
   
}
```

Comment: `linkedList` is the name of a function that returns a `node*`. `struct linkedList` (the type of `myList`) is not defined anywhere. To avoid confusion, I suggest giving unique names to your functions and structs.

Comment: You seem to be trying to write C++ in  C.

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of your code - use consistent indentation, line spacing, etc.  You will find at least a couple of problems when you do so.  Then you need to take a hard look at the names you have actually defined in the code.  There's no `struct linkedList` or `struct createList` type definition.  Finally, standard C does not allow for nested function definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be simplifying the explanations, so the terms that I will use might not be the correct one.

Proper and consistent indentation would always make your code easier to read and to fix. There were missing semi-colons too, you should watch out for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* head;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* linkedList();


int main()
{
    struct linkedList* myList = (struct createList*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    myList.addNode(5);
    myList.addNode(10);
    myList.addNode(13);

    printf("%d\n", myList.search(10));
    printf("The linked list is this big: %d\n", myList.getSize);
}


node* linkedList()
{   
    node* head;
    node* current;
    node* next;

    addNode (int x)
    {
        node keephead = head;
        current = head;

        while (current.next = NULL)
        {
            if (current.next = NULL)
            {
                current.next = node* newnode;
                newnode.data = x;
                newnode.next = NULL;
                newnode.head = keephead;
            }

            if (head = NULL)
            {     
                head = current;
            }
        }
    }

    int getSize ()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        node countNodes = head;

        while (countNodes.next != NULL)
        {
            countNodes = countNodes.next;
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }

    int search (int value)
    {
        int index = 0;
        node searchNode = head;

        while (searchNode.next != NULL)
        {
            searchNode = searchNode.next;
            index++;

            if(node.value = data)
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                index = -1;
            }
        }

        return index;
   }
}
```

---

In `main()`, you should add the `return 0;` at the end of the function as it is an [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079089/implicit-int-return-value-of-c-function) (AKA not a good thing to do). You could also change it to `void main()`, but it doesn't compile in clang.

```
    printf("%d\n", myList.search(10));
    printf("The linked list is this big: %d\n", myList.getSize);

    return 0;
}
```

You can't put a function within a function in C (nested functions). Put `addNode()`,  `getSize()`, and `search()` outside the `linkedList()` function.

```
node* linkedList()
{   
    node* head;
    node* current;
    node* next;
}

addNode (int x)
{
    node keephead = head;
    ...
}

int getSize ()
{
    int counter = 0;
    ...
    return counter;
}

int search (int value)
{
    int index = 0;
    ...
    return index;
}
```

`linkedList()` does literally nothing now and should be removed.

```
    struct node* next;
} node;


int main()
{
    struct linkedList* myList = (struct createList*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ...
    printf("The linked list is this big: %d\n", myList.getSize);

    return 0;
}

void addNode (int x)
{
    node keephead = head;
```

In `main()`, myList is the head of the currently empty linked-list, so it should be initialized to `NULL`. There's no `linkedList` data type, only `node`. Change it to:

```
node* myList = NULL;
```

You seem to be applying `addNode()`,  `getSize()`, and `search()` to a variable, but C doesn't have that feature (C++ have it though). Add the linked-list head as an argument instead. `addNode()` needs the `&` address operator since it will be changing where the head starts.

```
addNode(&myList, 5);
addNode(&myList, 10);
addNode(&myList, 13);

printf("%d\n", search(myList, 10));
printf("The linked list is this big: %d\n", getSize(myList));
```

Update the function parameters of `addNode()`. In the while condition `current.next = NULL` and if statements, you were using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator `!=` or `==`. You used the variables `current` and `newnode`, but never declared it anywhere in the function. There were lots of logic errors here. Change it to:

```
void addNode (node** head, int x)
{
    node* current = *head;
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    newnode->data = x;
    newnode->head = *head;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = newnode;
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;

        //current is now the last node of linked list
        current->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

Do the same for the function parameters of `getSize()` and `search()`. Use `node *` instead for `countNodes` and `searchNode`. `->` is the operator for accessing the members of a struct pointer. if statement should be put before it goes to the next node, as it would always skip the first node if left as it is. `index` should be put before the if statement so the index would update before it breaks out of the loop.

```
int getSize (node* head)
{
    int counter = 0;
    node* countNodes = head;

    while (countNodes != NULL)
    {
        countNodes = countNodes->next;
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}


int search (node* head, int value)
{
    int index = 0;
    node* searchNode = head;

    while (searchNode != NULL)
    {
        index++;

        if(searchNode->data == value)
            break;

        searchNode = searchNode->next;
    }

    if(searchNode->data != value)
        index = -1;

    return index;
}
```

Add the function prototypes before `main()`.

```
void addNode (node** head, int x);
int getSize (node* head);
int search (node* head, int value);


int main()
{
    node* myList = NULL;
```

Everything should work properly now.

Comment: [main()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/2472827) and [11.12a](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html) provide more details.

Comment: For the search function, is it possible to search by index and not by value? For example, is it  possible to find the second index without telling the value?