# Value returned when printed is different in C (Recursion Problem)

Tags: c, recursion, output

So I got this question in my end-sem:

```
//The value returned by sam(3,0) of the below function is:
#include <stdio.h>
int sam(int n,int a)
{

    if(n==0)
         return a;
    else
    {
        a+=n;
        sam(--n, a);
        a+=n;
    }
}
```

I calculate using Tree-method and got the answer as 6. But if I compile and directly print return I get 2.

```
int main()
{
    printf("%ld",sam(3,0));
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: 2

I checked again and again with what is wrong and couldn't understand. The mystery is if I print(a) just before it returns. It returns 6 (what I calculated).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sam(int n,int a)
{
    if(n==0){
        printf("%d",a); //Check the change here
        return a;
    }
    else{
        a+=n;
        sam(--n,a);
        a+=n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    sam(3,0);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: 6

If I explain this I get 4 marks. Enough to change my grade

Comment: Sounds like cheating in exam...

Comment: Crank up your compiler warnings.

Comment: What does `sam` return when `n != 0`?

Comment: I genuinely solved it using pen and paper. This time atlesat.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly? Are you saying that was the definition of the function given on your exam?  Push back; that is undefined behavior.  (Unless there's a copy-paste error.)

Comment: `sam` when `n!=0` returns the else statement running the recursion

Comment: [Implicit int return value of C function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079437) It's ok to not return a value, but UB if you try to use the result of such a function. So the answer is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @BhaskarMishra Look more closely.  When `n != 0`, the function is called again and the recursion happens but no value is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of formatting assistance, please note that the below function only explicitly returns when `n` is `0`. Otherwise it performs recursion, but uselessly since it never returns any value created by the recursion.

As a result, you find yourself in the realm of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int sam(int n, int a) {
>     if (n == 0)
>         return a;
>     else {
>         a += n;
>         sam(--n, a);
>         a += n;
>     } 
> }
> ```