# My function isn't returning a value

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to calculate the price of items (customers get a discount off regular price of the item if they purchase 10 or more of the item). It's all working well except for the `int Product::fulfillOrder(int orderq)` function. It says a value must be returned, but the `orderq` should be returning a value for the function to use (I believe I did it right). Here's the code for the problem function:

```
int Product::fulfillOrder(int orderq)
{
    if (orderq < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        orderq = 0;
        cout << "Shipped: " << orderq << endl;
    }

    else if (orderq <= Quantity)
    {
        orderq = Quantity;
        Quantity -= orderq;
        cout << "Shipped: " << orderq << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        orderq = Quantity;
        orderq = 0;
        cout << "Shipped: " << orderq << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the return statement

Comment: When I added that it gave me a number like 9.108+e10. I removed it because of that. Do you think I should change it to like "return 1;"?

Comment: Apparently you meant `void Product::fulfillOrder`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a return statement mandatory for C++ functions that do not return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784075/is-a-return-statement-mandatory-for-c-functions-that-do-not-return-void)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step, query its state, thus understanding what is happenning

Comment: What does g++ -Wall -Wextra and -g mean? I'm really new to C++ and I've never heard of these terms.

Comment: @RezTheRipper It generates more warnings and compiles with debugging information. https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add

> return orderq;

at the end of the function.

Comment: I tried adding it to the bottom, but I still keep getting the strange value.

Comment: strange value in sense? What return you are getting. I hope "Quantity" is some macro or constant.

Comment: I keep getting a number like 9.28102+e12 whenever I run it. Quantity is an integer that I have to put in for each different item.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is missing. If you want to return an int you must return what you need.
What I can see in your code is that you put the input parameter to 0 whatever condition is.
You must check just if the input is greater than 0 because it doesn't make sense if the order is less than 0. Something impossible.
Meaning why do you want to check if the order is below zero? No sense, check if its greater in order to go inside the calculus.

When the input is -1 the two first 'if' statements are true. Also you are doing something like:

```
orderq = Quantity
Quantity = orderq
```

If you want to exchange values, you need a third auxiliar variable, but analyzing your code and what you need to do. You need to resolve your problem on paper first. Then coded it.

Good luck!