# access pixel and check if is inf pixel

Tags: c++, opencv

I searched on the web and didn't find any good answer for my problem. So this is my question: 
 I am using OpenCV and have a function called `replaceInvalidDisparties` and I have to search through the pixels and check if the actual value is `inf` and there is a standard function in `OpenCv` called `cvIsInf(double value)` to check if the value is `inf`, but somehow i always get segmentation fault.

```
using namespace cv;
cv::Mat replaceInvalidDisparities(const cv::Mat &original_disp)
{
  cv::Mat output = orignal_disp.clone();

  //access pixel

  for(int i = 0; i< output.rows; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<output.cols; j++)
   {
      //now here i want to check if the actual pixel is inf
      cvIsInf(output.at<double>(i,j));
   }
  }
}
```

But somehow it always give me a segmentation fault. Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, i see is that you don't use return value of the cvIsInf function. According to opencv docs: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gae04046b1211c77ff19a535bd78c15964, The function returns 1 if the argument is a plus or minus infinity (as defined by IEEE754 standard) and 0 otherwise.

So, you should replace your code inside loop to smth like this:

```
if (cvIsInf(output.at<double>(i,j))) {
  output.at<double>(i,j) = new_value;
}
```

The second problem is that you doesn't return output matrix from the function:

```
return output;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah i tried this but somehow there is always a segmentationfault if i run my program dont know why...

Comment: Are you sure that segmentation fault caused by this function?

Comment: yeah, normally when i erase this two for loops and the cvisInf functijon there are no problems

Comment: Are you sure that your original_disp Mat contains doubles and not other type?

Comment: i found my problem it was the opencV 3.1 cause the program only runs on 2.4.9

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you do return a value. Not returning a value is an undefined behavior: [Is a return statement mandatory for C++ functions that do not return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784075/is-a-return-statement-mandatory-for-c-functions-that-do-not-return-void).

Rest of the function doesn't seems to be the cause of the segmentation fault, I would suggest changing

`cv::Mat output = orignal_disp.clone();`

to

`cv::Mat output(100, 100, CV_64F);`

Just to make sure your matrix is not ill-formed. 
(Was going to comment; didn't have enough reputation.)

Comment: thx! i found the problem it was the opencV version but thanks for the tip!