# Not returning value from function cause segfault

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault

Found strange behavior that i don't understand:

```
std::vector<std::string> subdomainVisits(std::vector<std::string> &cpdomains)
{
    // return std::vector<std::string>();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     std::vector<std::string> data = { "9001 discuss.leetcode.com" };
     auto result = subdomainVisits(data);
     return 0;
 }
```

In this case commented `return` in `subdomainVisits` function causes Segmentation fault(use gcc version 7.3.0 (Debian 7.3.0-19) ). Uncommenting fix this problem.

Why it happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a return statement mandatory for C++ functions that do not return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784075/is-a-return-statement-mandatory-for-c-functions-that-do-not-return-void)

Comment: @AMA yep, that issue very similar with mine. Thanks for the pointing.

Comment: @AMA But still trying to understand what may happens(in terms of UB) and what cause segfault when program tries to build return value from nothing.

Comment: @Bathsheba `-S` compiler key would be enough for me?

Comment: @boddicheg you would have to look at the generated gcc assembly to figure out what really happens. Tried [godbolting](https://godbolt.org/) it?

Comment: @Bathsheba Will do. Thanks for a new bookmark.

Comment: @boddicheg: Asking what happens when what happens is undefined is not really logical. If you want to see what the compiler has done with code that has undefined constructs then check the generated assembly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of your program as written is *undefined*.

A non-`void` function **must** have an explicit return value on all control paths.

The only exception to this is `main`, which has an implicit `return 0;`.

A fair number of compilers will warn you of trivial cases such as the above. Do you not have the warning level set high enough? (Pass `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to "turn up" the warning level on gcc.)

Note that the C++ standard does not require a compiler to fail compilation: theoretical computer science (the *halting problem*) tells us that reachability is impossible to prove.

Comment: Shouldn't that be an error rather than a warning in c++?

Comment: clang sometimes doesn't even put the ret assembly instruction when you aren't returning a value when you should, soo your program keep executing whatever is in memory after the fonction

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Absolutely not. Added remarks on that.

Comment: No warnings at all when compiling using command `g++ name.cpp`. Anyway, thanks:)

Comment: @boddicheg: `-Wall`, `-Wextra` ?

Comment: @Bathsheba Got warning with this flag

Comment: In case you code with exceptions, it might be useful precise that non-void function have to either throw something, or return something.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour.

Add `-Wreturn-type` to options to prevent running into this.