# why a function with returntype in c works with out return statement?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can you return from a non-void function without returning a value without producing a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pro)

```
void main()
{
    int y=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("%d\n",Testing());
    y=Testing();
    printf("%d",y);
    getch();
}
int  Testing()
{
    int x=100;
    //return x;
}

Result 
512
4
```

i am not returning any thing from the testing function still value is coming?

Another Question also

```
void main()
{
    char Testing();
    int y=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("%d\n",Testing());
    if(Testing())
        printf("if--exi");
    else
        printf("else--exi");
    getch();
}
char Testing()
{
    char y;
    //return y;
}

Result

0
if--exi
```

if printf is commented then result is

```
else--exi
```

why is it happening like that

Comment: I'd think the function without return would be Undefined behaviour and would trigger at least a warning...

Comment: warning is there but it is still working what is happening internal?

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++ at the same time? These languages are significantly different in this regard.

Comment: Er... By removing the [C++] tag you essentially invalidated the Mark B's answer, which you yourself marked as accepted. The conclusion is correct, but the explanation given in that answer is C++-specific, i.e. the explanation is technically incorrect in the context of C language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function declared to return a value that reaches a path without a return has undefined behavior. You just got unlucky that it appeared to still be returning a semi-plausible value. The compiler assumes that a `return` is called in all exits from the function and that a return value will be available at a particular location.

In your second example effectively anything can happen, including returning different values each call.

g++ has a warning to detect this problem, and it's highly worth enabling.

Comment: *"appeared to work"*? How can you say that? :P What output do you predict/expect? and on what ground?

Comment: @Nawaz: as opposed to crashing outright.

Comment: Your answer is correct from C++ language point of view, but not in C. In C language just reaching the end of a value-returning function does not cause undefined behavior. In C undefined behavior occurs only when you attempt to use the "returned" value in the caller. The OP's code is still broken in both languages, of course, but for different reasons. Judging by the title of the question, the OP was implying C, not C++.

Comment: @Nawaz I changed my wording to hopefully be more clear. I meant that "something" happened as opposed to failing to compile or crashing out.

Answer (score 3):

Why is your question tagged C and C++ at the same time, while the title specifically refers to C? These two languages are significantly different in this regard.

In C language such functions "work" because the language requires them to work. Why not? The function that is declared with some return type might still do some useful work (besides returning anything). So, not having a `return` statement in such a function is perfectly fine from the formal point of view. It is not a good programming practice though. The function will work as long as you are not trying to use the returned value (which the function didn't really return). You are trying to use that value, which makes the behavior of your code undefined. You are claiming that it "works". In reality it doesn't. What happens in this case and why - these questions have no answers. For all means and purposes your code's behavior is essentially random and unpredictable.

In C++ language functions that "forget" to return a value with a `return` statement always immediately lead to undefined behavior, regardless of whether the value is used by the caller or not.

Comment: "What happens in this case and why - these questions have no answers. For all means and purposes your code's behavior is essentially random and unpredictable."  -- REALLY?  I would say that what happens is the return value appears to be whatever was left over in the EAX register, which is not very mysterious at all.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: That might possibly apply to a very specific build of the code, built by a very specific compiler with a very specific set of compiler options and a very specific set of heuristic decisions made by the compiler's internal algorithms on a very specific hardware platform. Meanwhile, I was treating this question as a generic question about C language, since it is tagged [C].

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: One might argue that nothing in our lives is really random and unpredictable and that everything can be predicted by tracing the paths of specific atoms (or some other particles) from the moment of Big Bang. To some degree (as an "ad absurdum" analogy) that's pretty close to what you are advocating with your EAX theory. I, on the other hand, don't see it as a particularly productive approach.

Comment: One might make an "ad absurdum" analogy, but then one would be arguing with one's own straw man.  In point of fact, understanding the C ABI of your platform is part of using C.  There may be those who claim otherwise, but they probably don't work on device drivers in C.

Answer (score 2):

Its just random junk in memory you're getting back, hence, each call in the second example produces different results

Answer (score 2):

it is Undefined behavior to get the return value of function which is declared to not return anything.

Undefined behavior means that anything is possible and the outcome of the operation is not defined by the C++ standard. You cannot estimate or approximate the outcome in any of the program runs.

Answer (score 1):

You're causing undefined behaviour, so literally *any* output is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you are invoking "undefined behavior." Undefined behavior behaves, well, without definition. If the behavior of your program is undefined, it might print 512, 4, 99, or even the complete text of the Gettysburg Address.

I wouldn't describe the results you showed as 'working' in any reasonable sense of that word.

P.s. If you are using the GNU Compiler Collection, I recommend using *at least* these switches: "-Wall -Werror".

P.p.s. In years gone by, in the days before ANSI-standard C, a certain non-optimizing Z-80 C compiler would accept this program fragment:

```
int ReturnThree() {
  3;
}
```

and produce the same code as if the user had specified:

```
int ReturnThree() {
  return 3;
}
```