# Default return value of a boolean type return function in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can you return from a non-void function without returning a value without producing a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pro)

According to the c++ standard what should be the return value of the following function.

```
bool done()
{
     // no return value
}
```

Comment: Would you like us to read the whole section to you, or just summarize?

Comment: I think booleans are either true or false. Returning "unknown" is a third state so you no longer have a boolean function.

Comment: No, it's like Schrödinger's cat. It has one of the two states (true/false), but until you read the value, you can't tell which one. So you should assume the value is in "superposition" of both states :-D

Answer (score 6):

This would be undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Comment: Can my computer explode if I do that? :)

Comment: could you please point to an authenticated source.

Comment: @Vlad: Exploding would be standards-conforming behavior. 8v)

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: Yes, that would be legal according to the Standard.

Comment: Mine just said "P=NP". It is dumb because N is definitely not equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Although it returns a value, it is undefined.