# C++ Selection Statement returning true

Tags: c++

Something is wrong with my playerWin function.  It keeps telling me I won.  I feel like I haven't put any x's on the board to win though.  What's wrong with my logic?  This isn't homework.  I haven't programmed in forever and my first language was Java.  I'm trying to learn c++ and picked tic tac toe to give me something to do.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int boardSize = 3;
char board[3][3] = {'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n' };


void printBoard() {
  for (int i=0; i < boardSize; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < boardSize; j++) {
      cout << board[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  } 
}

// void playerMove() { };

bool playerWin() { 
  if ((board[0][0] == 'x') && (board[1][0] == 'x') && 
      (board[2][0] == 'x') || 

      (board[0][1] == 'x') && (board[1][1] == 'x') &&
      (board[2][1] == 'x') ||

      (board[0][2] == 'x') && (board[1][2] == 'x') &&
      (board[2][2] == 'x') ||

      (board[0][0] == 'x') && (board[0][1] == 'x') &&
      (board[0][2] == 'x') ||

      (board[1][0] == 'x') && (board[1][1] == 'x') &&
      (board[1][2] == 'x') ||

      (board[2][0] == 'x') && (board[2][1] == 'x') &&
      (board[2][2] == 'x') ||

      (board[0][0] == 'x') && (board[1][1] == 'x') &&
      (board[2][2] == 'x') ||

      (board[2][0] == 'x') && (board[1][1] == 'x') &&
      (board[0][2] == 'x')) {

        return true;
  } 
}

int main() {

  // game loop

  char play = 'y';

  cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe\n";

  do {

    if (playerWin()) {
      cout << "Looks like you won!" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "You didn't win!";
    }

    break;

    // after game is over ask if want to play again here
    // cout << "Would you like to play Tic Tac Toe? \n";
    // cin >> play;

  } while (play = 'y');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default return value of a boolean type return function in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529432/default-return-value-of-a-boolean-type-return-function-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an explicit `return false;`, when the `if` statement fails.

Run a stackoverflow search for "undefined behavior", for the rest of the story.

If your compiler yelled at you when you tried to compile this, let this be a lesson: don't ignore your compiler when it's yelling at you.

If your compiler didn't yell at you when you tried to compile this, find a warning option, or a setting, that makes the compiler yell at you in similar situations, in the future. This will save a lot of head-scratching.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  The compiler didn't warn me.  I'm using g++ with cygwin.  I'll have to figure out how to turn those warnings on.  Thank you!

Comment: @NickBlack: `g++ -Wall`

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your example, I have 10 warnings.  These:

```
test.cpp:20:52: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
  if ((board[0][0] == 'x') && (board[1][0] == 'x') && 
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.cpp:20:52: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
  if ((board[0][0] == 'x') && (board[1][0] == 'x') && 
                                                   ^
test.cpp:23:52: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
      (board[0][1] == 'x') && (board[1][1] == 'x') &&
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.cpp:23:52: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
      (board[0][1] == 'x') && (board[1][1] == 'x') &&
                                                   ^
```

should probably be fixed, but aren't the issue.  This however:

```
test.cpp:46:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

is likely your issue, and should be addressed.

In addition, I found this:

```
test.cpp:71:17: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
  } while (play = 'y');
           ~~~~~^~~~~
test.cpp:71:17: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
  } while (play = 'y');
                ^
           (         )
test.cpp:71:17: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
  } while (play = 'y');
                ^
                ==
```

and is your compiler telling you that you've done an assignment, which looking at your code isn't what you want to do.

I'd recommend building with -Wall and fixing the warnings.  Your compiler is trying to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I see that assignment statement error and I'll have to research using -Wall flag.  I'm not very experienced in anything--but especially using command line.  I just didn't want to be bogged down in an IDE.  I want to learn to use the command line!  Thank you.