# Is a blank return statement at the end of a function whos return type is void necessary?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, gnu

Most of the questions on SO refer to non-void return types, but we are having a flame war at work about this and wanted to find out what the community thought.

```
void DoSomething()
{
   return; // Is this needed?
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr) discussion, it looks like the issue of having an undefined behavior deals with functions of non-void return types.  Do void return types have this same undefined behavior, or is it only in the non-void returning function?

My concern is that this will just end up as a terrible coding style that isn’t justified by anything.  However if it’s also an undefined behavior for void return functions, then I can see the need for adding it to the coding standard.  If the answer is different for C vs C++ this is ok too.

§ 6.6.3 The return statement

> 2 A return statement without an expression can be used only in
>   functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the
>   return type of void, a contrsuctor(12.1), or a destructor(12.4).

§ 6.6.3/2

> Flowing off the end of a function is
>   equivalent to a return with no value;
>   this results in undefined behavior **in
>   a value-returning function.**

Comment: You answered your own question with that standard reference :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No; that is not needed.

You only need to write `return;` if you want to return early and skip the rest of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, `return;` is never needed in a function that is not breaking out of itself early.

Answer (score 2):

Return is explicit.  It conveys that the author clearly understood that there was no value to return.

BTW - there should only be one return allowed, but that is another discussion (so don't answer it here!!).

Also, from a code maintenance point of view, "**return;**" provides a convenient spot to add a value, if the function is ever changed from void.

Leave it in!  The object is not to see who can write the function with the fewest lines.