# Why does this C++ compile?

Tags: c++, function, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can you return from a non-void function without returning a value without producing a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr)

Why does `gcc 4.6.1` compile the following function without a return statement?

```
uint32_t& siof_solution() {
   static uint32_t example = (uint32_t) 7; // Doesn't really matter
   // return example;
}
```

It returns `1`.  *I seen't it*.

Comment: Hey, it gives you a warning, isn't that enough? There was a switch to stop compilation on warning...

Comment: I've seen similar cases with the Visual C++ compiler also.  Where a function was declared with a return value, I forgot to put the return statement and somehow it compiled and returned a value!  In my case the return value was garbage which was interpreted as true.  Not sure why.

Comment: **Always** compile with all warnings enabled. Don't post until you've tried to compile with all warnings.

Comment: Woops -- didn't see that quesiton ildjarn.  Thanks (voted to close).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ functions aren't required to return a value even if they say they do.  If they don't, the result is undefined behavior.  In your case, through Sheer Dumb Luck the code seems t be working, but it's not portable and not safe.  This could crash, return a garbage pointer, cause a debug error, etc.

I think the reason for this decision is mostly backwards-compatibility with C, though I'm not sure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Sheer Dumb Luck" is the key phrase here.

Answer (score 0):

Return check is turned off somehow. I don't even remember if it is required in C++ at all. The returned value in your case is memory garbage.