# C++ Boolean function returning 56

Tags: c++

I have a function to return a bool:

```
bool restart()
{
    std::string answer;
    bool answered = false;
    while(answered == false)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "Do you want to play again? y/n : ";
        cin >> answer;
        if(answer == "y" || answer == "Y" || answer == "1" || answer == "yes")
        {return true;}
        if(answer == "n" || answer == "N" || answer == "0" || answer == "no")
        {return false;}
    }
}
```

When I call it using:

```
cout << restart();
```

I get the output:

```
Do you want to play again? y/n : y
56
```

Can anyone see how to fix this strange problem? 
Thanks in advance.

My WIP code as it is now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void drawScreen(int grid[3][3]);                               //
int movef(int grid[3][3], bool playersMove);
int updateGrid(int grid[3][3], int move, bool playersMove);
bool hasWon(int grid[3][3]);
bool swapMover(bool playersMove);                              //
bool restart();
void endGame();

int main()
{
    int grid[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    bool appRunning = true, gameRunning = true, playersMove = true;
    int move;

    // tests //
    std::cout << restart();
    // tests //

    //while(appRunning == true)
    //{
    //    while(gameRunning == true)
    //    {
    //        drawScreen(grid);
    //        move = movef(grid, playersMove);
    //        grid[3][3] = updateGrid(grid, move, playersMove);
    //        drawScreen(grid);
    //        gameRunning = hasWon(grid);
    //        playersMove = swapMover(playersMove);
    //    }
    //    appRunning = restart();
    //}
    //endGame();
    }

    void drawScreen(int grid[3][3])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
             for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
             {
             if(grid[i][j] == 10){cout << "X  ";if(j == 2){cout << endl << endl;}}
             if(grid[i][j] == 11){cout << "O  ";if(j == 2){cout << endl << endl;}}
             if(grid[i][j] != 10 && grid[i][j] != 11){cout << grid[i][j] << "  ";
             if(j == 2){cout << endl << endl;}}
             }
        }
   }

  int movef(int grid[3][3], bool playersMove)
  {
       return 0;
  }

  int updateGrid(int grid[3][3], int move, bool playersMove)
  {
       return 0;
  }

  bool hasWon(int grid[3][3])
  {
      return false;
  }

  bool swapMover(bool playersMove)
  {
       if(playersMove == true){return false;}
       if(playersMove == false){return true;}
  }

bool restart()
{
    std::string answer;
    bool answered = false;
    while(answered == false)
    {
       cout << endl << endl << "Do you want to play again? y/n : ";
       cin >> answer;
       if(answer == "y" || answer == "Y" || answer == "1" || answer == "yes")
       {return true;}
        if(answer == "n" || answer == "N" || answer == "0" || answer == "no")
       {return false;}
    }
}

void endGame()
{

}
```

Comment: How do you print the returned value? `cout << restart()`?

Comment: Yes. It was used as part of my main loop. A bool value gameRunning was set to it using gameRunning = restart(); and I kept getting 56. So I tested the function itself using cout << restart(); and I still get 56

Comment: Does it return 56 in the case of "no" as well?

Comment: Well technically anything not 0 is `true`. I'm not sure if the standard mandates 1. Your code might be able to be simplified to just `std::cout << true;` as well; does that produce the same result?

Comment: @user1487087: Do you have any strange `typedef`s somewhere?

Comment: Yes. In the case of "no" 56 is still the result.

Comment: @user1487087: Does the program start/stop as expected ? Regardless of output?

Comment: std::cout produces the same result.

Comment: Ok, that's odd if both `true` and `false` do that. Are you including any strange headers, or have defines or anything?

Comment: @user1487087: Can you post your entire code, please? (If it's small enough.) And please include included headers and other preprocessor directives.

Comment: Doug - The program works with no errors. It is just that answering "no" and "yes" both return 56 and so it restarts the game regardless of what the using inputs here.

Comment: well my code is to make a tick tack toe game and is in early stages so    I cannot really post my code. I am making the needed functions one by one and testing them as I go. I will build it all together at the end. This function is all there is when testing and main contails only the cout command.

Comment: @user1487087: If it's in early stages, posting your code shouldn't be a problem... go ahead and just post what you have. It will help. A lot.

Comment: my headers are: #include <iostream> #include <cstdlib>

Comment: @user1487087 Did you reproduce this problem more than once? I [cannot](http://ideone.com/aZhDV). Also note that you might get into an infinite loop...

Comment: @user1487087, The smallest complete sample that reproduces the problem is what we love. See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @user1487087: The code as posted works perfectly fine in gcc4.6 so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @user1487087: Yes, if you can, please [reproduce the problem on CodePad](http://codepad.org/yuL7MGAS).

Comment: entire code added now (sorry for the incompleteness)

Comment: btw functions are all out of main I just indented it wrong when copying it in.

Comment: Try using `boolalpha( cout );` before you display the value.

Comment: @user1487087: Your complete code works [perfectly fine on gcc4.3](http://ideone.com/BASWY). What compiler are you using?

Comment: codepad: http://codepad.org/LGtEoIlh

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here, but you have no return value defined outside of the while loop. If somehow you get outside of it, you do not return a value (though I have no idea what behavior is expected or even if any behavior is expected in this case)

Comment: Yes, all control paths should lead to a return value.

Comment: I have got it working. I added return false; at the end of the function now it works fine. Any Idea how this happens?

Comment: As is the function cannot exits the while loop, but if it did, OP would get an undefined behavior (warning "not all control paths return a value").

Comment: @user1487087 what compiler are you using ? Any difference between "debug" and "release" modes ?

Comment: Ok. thanks everyone for the help. I'm new to stack overflow. Do you know how I set this so answered?

Comment: You can post an answer yourself if you found the solution !

Comment: @user1487087: You can accept the correct answer (checkmark underneath its score). In this case (since there is non so far) you can post an answer and accept your one answer.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the mingw32 compiler, when using g++ 4.8 it works fine. It seems to be a compiler error. (thanks to grizzly)

Answer (score 4):

[This is somewhat of a repost of my comment since OP said it solved his problem]

You have no return value defined outside of the while loop. If somehow you get outside of it, you do not return a value (though I have no idea what behavior is expected or even if any behavior is expected in this case)

To make my answer a bit more thorough, I have found this:
[Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr)

Comment: Indeed GCC warns about this. I have no clue how it would get out, though.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm making a guess. Your original code has the line

```
grid[3][3] = updateGrid(grid, move, playersMove);
```

And your grid definition is

```
int grid[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

This means that your are writing out of the array bounds. This is undefined behavior.
Please correct this and check if your program works as expected.