# How does this C int function works without a return statement?

Tags: c, recursion, return

I've this C code which I was sure it wouldn't work, but it does.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* find (int* a, int val) {
    if (*a == val)
        return a;
    else
        find(a+1, val);
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int *b;

    b = find(a, 7);

    printf("%d\n", *b);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, I get a warning from gcc since it lacks a return statement inside the else branch of the `find` function. However, it works perfectly.

Why does this happen? How does it know to return an int through the recursive function? Of course, the last calls returns an int, but I'm calling it in a void context.

Comment: As long as you refuse to tell us what `trova` does, how do you expect a meaningful answer? For all we know it calls `exit(0);` immediately.

Comment: It does not compile, there is no `trova` function definition in your program. Paste a compilable a test code.

Comment: Ops. I forgot to translate it, `trova` is Italian for `find'. Sorry.

Comment: Now it's fixed. Sorry for this dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to write `find` instead of `trova` (I knew learning Italian would come in handy some day :), the answer is that this does not work perfectly. It "works" purely by chance, by virtue of undefined behavior.

Most likely, the deepest recursive call pushes the return value into some register, which the higher-level calls don't touch because they don't have a return statement, and when the caller inspects that register, the return value of the deepest call is still there. You can't rely on this, though.

Answer (score 8):

**This code is not a valid C code, and the behavior of such code is not defined.**

One reason why it work may be that there is no operation after the last call in `find` which **may** result in the return value of the recursive call staying in the return register (probably eax).

**But again - the behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 4):

This *seems* to be working, but it is *undefined behavior*. It just happen that in your particular implementation/platform `b` takes the latest value returned from `find`. However, on a different implementation/platform this may as well crash.

Comment: To be a little bit more specific: the `return a` has the side effect of setting up the return register which does not get cleared. *But this is undefined behaviour*, yes

Answer (score -1):

I can't find a reference, but I remember from years ago, in GCC, the return value register  (as allocated on the CPU) always had the last return value, so if you computed some value and return with no value, the previous value persists.  It seems like a bad practice to use this "feature".

Maybe see also

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr](http://forums.freebsd.org/archive/index.php/t-32752.html)

[C: default return value if no value is given?](http://forums.freebsd.org/archive/index.php/t-32752.html)

That says:
Uniballer
June 15th, 2012, 01:44
The behavior is undefined by the C language, because you didn't do in the function what you said you were going to do in the function declaration. In practice, on x86 the value of the function will be whatever happens to be in register eax on return.