# Why does this recursive function return the correct value?

Tags: c, recursion, return, return-value

Running a recursive function such as this one (compiled in gcc 7.3.1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[] = {5,1,2,6,7,3};
int arraySize = 6;

int recfind(int value, int index)
{
    if (arr[index] == value)
        return 1;
    if (index >= arraySize)
        return 0;
    // return recfind(value, ++index);
    recfind(value, ++index);
 }

int main() {
    printf("found 6? %d\n", recfind(6, 0));
    printf("found 9? %d\n", recfind(9, 0));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
found 6? 1
found 9? 0
```

Why does this work? Since the result of the recursive `recfind` call is not returned, how is the return value of higher-level calls chosen?

Comment: The function is specified to return something, but doesn't. Aren't you wondering how you can even get away with that? Regardless of the result?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, that's exactly what I'm wondering.

Comment: Trying to discuss behavior of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is pointless.

Comment: Your compiler should raise a warning about this.

Comment: This is highly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the

Comment: One of the many nasal demons being released by this could be that more or less accidentally the return value of the parent call happens to be the return value of the last child call, because/in spite of the lack or a `return`.

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14753444/2730823

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C section is 6.9.1 from N1256:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
>   function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So the behaviour of your program is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> Why does this work?

There is a possibility that the target + compiler you are using doesn't tamper the register containing the return value from last (recursive) function call. C doesn't mandate this mechanism for returning value in specs.

So, though it may sound sensible, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: The question didn't ask about C++.

Comment: @aschepler it was tagged C/C++.

Comment: @aschepler Indeed, I wasn't sure if it being C or C++ would have any bearing on this (and it if it did, I would've been interested in what exactly that bearing was)

Comment: @gandalf3 In C function returning by value may not return **as long as** caller doesn't use the return value. In C++, it doesn't matter whether caller is using the return value or not, the bahaviour is undefined if function did not return.