# Is there a default return value of C++ functions?

Tags: c++, cygwin

I am surprised that a file containing the following lines of code is successfully compiled and linker produces an executable. I thought that all functions, except `main`, must have a valid `return` statement unless the return type is `void`.

```
int foo(){}
double bar(){}
int main(){}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that all functions, except `main` must have a valid return statement unless the return type is `void`.

Yes, they must. You'll get undefined behaviour if they don't.

> What am I missing?

If the function is sufficiently complicated, it can be difficult or impossible for the compiler to tell whether all return paths return a value; so the compiler isn't required to diagnose the error.

Most compilers will issue warnings in many cases, if you enable warnings.

Comment: I find this to be an excellent use case for a static analyzer.

Comment: @faranwath: Indeed; although a good compiler should include that analysis, and it's not always possible to detect statically.

Comment: I find you last comment interesting. Care to share an example? I cannot think of a plausible situation from the top of my mind.

Comment: @faranwath: For example, a `switch` statement with a `return` in each branch, where you (but not the compiler) can prove that the value can only be one of the handled cases. On a tiny embedded system, you might not want the overhead of handling the (theoretically impossible) default case.

Comment: @faranwath: More abstractly, tracing all possible return paths is equivalent to solving the halting problem, which is well known to be impossible to solve statically in the general case.

Comment: I see it better now with the analogy you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Not returning a value from a function that says it does is undefined behavior. It compiles and links, but don't expect the program to behave correctly.

If you compile with a high warning level, the compiler will tell you about it.

Comment: I thinker Cpp should let virtual functions and callbacks have a default return value specified by the server of the callback. Example, void onCall() def_return (-1) so that the server is guaranteed to have a proper return value.