# When return type is default in function header and return statement is not provided, why is undefined behavior happening?

Tags: c, function, undefined-behavior

When I execute the following program in GCC, I expect output to be 0 because the return statement is missing in max() function, but when I execute it, the output is 10. What is the reason for such behavior??

```
#include <stdio.h>

max(int x, int y) 
{ 
    if (x > y) 
    return x; 
    else
    x=5;
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
    int a = 10, b = 20; 

    // Calling above function to find max of 'a' and 'b' 
    int m = max(a, b); 

    printf("%d", m); 
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? Do you compile it as C or C++ code?

Comment: Will not compile in c++, so it is C :-)

Comment: @Klaus It would with `-fpermissive` (whatever it does in such case).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: To be more precise: It violates against C++ standard! That some compilers accept that code with disabling C++ rules may be true :-)

Comment: I guess the value of the first argument of `max(int a,int b)` is assigned to `m`. I think the reason would be as whenever the function is called it is loaded on the stack by pushing necessary variables, maybe due to no return statement it is assuming the first argument as the return value. Try swapping `a` and `b` and you get `m=20`

Comment: The reason for such behavior is that the behavior in this case is _undefined_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a default return value of C++ functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234357/is-there-a-default-return-value-of-c-functions) spoiler: No, there is not. So don't do that.

Comment: Is it C or C++? Please decide, and remove the other tag.

Comment: OT: you should indent your code properly

Comment: We really need a canonical "why is undefined behaviour not defined the way I expected" question, because it seems to keep cropping up. Any good candidates?

Comment: _"why is undefined behavior happening?"_: what would _you_ expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good practice to see the assembly code for more clarification. Let's see the assembly code for the function `max(int,int)`.
Assembly code obtained from `gcc -S [filename].c`

```
max:                                 //max() function starts here
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc          
        endbr64
        pushq   %rbp                //Stack Push
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16      //ignore
        .cfi_offset 6, -16          //ignore
        movq    %rsp, %rbp          //ignore
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6     //ignore
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)      //move int a to base pointer register from offset of 4 bytes
        movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)      //move int b to base pointer register from offset of 8 bytes
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax      //move int a to extended ax register
        cmpl    -8(%rbp), %eax      //compare b>a
        jle     .L2                 //If cmp above succeeds execute this jle, as it checks for zero and carry flag
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax      //If cmp above fails start executing from this statement, int a is moved to extended ax register
        jmp     .L1                 //jump to L1
.L2:
        movl    $5, -4(%rbp)        //move number 5 to base pointer register from offset of 4 bytes
.L1:
        popq    %rbp                //Stack Pop
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8           //ignore
        ret                         //Return value of extended ax register to the caller and control also.
        .cfi_endproc
```

As, we can conclude from the above assembly code, no matter what the condition evaluates, it is always the extended ax register that is returned to the caller(for x86 system).
And the compiler for this case stored the first argument i.e. `a` to `eax` register.

Comment: I don't think it's really "a good practice" to analyse specific manifestations of undefined behaviour. It might be a good distraction in a moment when the programmer has nothing better to do... but the "good practice" is to fix the code so it does not have UB, rather than leave it and spend time looking at what ASM is generated for code that is defined as invalid.

Comment: In the context of analysing the UB I meant to check for the assembly code. As to why the program is returning a certain value when we didn't specified any return value.

Comment: Thank you @SourabhChoure, got clarified with reason.

Answer (score 4):

> When return type is default in function header and return statement is not provided, why is undefined behavior happening?

Because the standard does not define what should happen. Thus the catchy term "undefined behavior". If the standard does not define what should happen... then literally anything can happen, the code can behave in any way.

It is explicitly stated that your code has undefined behavior in [the standard C11 6.9.1p12](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12).

> What is the reason for such behavior??

Because the behavior is not defined, the compiler is not required to generate any code with any predictable behavior. So it generates some code that just happens to act as-if the function would have returned 10, but no one really cares because it can do what it wants.

The pragmatic answer comes from inspecting the assembly generated [from the compiler (godbolt link)](https://godbolt.org/z/vfbx1n) (once again, compiler can do what it wants). In `main` function compiler places `mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 10` then `mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]` then `mov     edi, eax` - ie. `edi` register has `10`. Then in `max` compiler does `mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi` and `mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]` then `ret`urns from the function - when `max` returns, the content of `eax` register has `10`. Because compiler uses `mov     esi, eax` to initialize arguments for `printf`, `printf` functions prints the value `10`, which is what is left over in the `eax` register.

Comment: Also try with optimization on (`-O3`) - there will be no code generated for `max` at all and the output is `0`.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk, got clarified with reason.

Answer (score 2):

> When I execute the following program in GCC

You don't execute something in the compiler!
You compile your code with gcc!

> I expect output to be 0 because the return statement is missing

Your expectation is simply wrong. C nor C++ have a "default return value in case of missing return statement" So you simply must provide an return statement if you function is not defined `void` with value to make your programme well formed!

Every compiler will give you at minimum a warning. You should allways compile with -Wall or better -Wextra -pedantic.

Comment: In C, you don't need to provide a `return` statement even if the function has a return type, and the program may be well-formed with defined behavior. You just may not use that return value. Such that `int f() { } int main() { f(); }` is ok. In C++, IIRC, this is [undefined behavior unconditionally](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2.sentence-9). But even in C++ I don't think this make the code ill-formed.

Comment: @DanielLangr what would be the return value, if no return statement is provided?? is it undefined or any specific value??

Comment: "if no return statement is provided" UB! I tested your code, fixed the missing int return type definition for max, compiled with c++ and the prog did not output anything, even more cout's are lost. Debugger shows invalid stack frame! It feels this is a fully thoeretical discussion! There is no default return value! So if you want correct code, provide a return value. To discuss if a program has UB and/or is ill formed or not did not help, as the program simply will not work.

Comment: @BBSusheelKumar "_what would be the return value, if no return statement is provided?"_ — That question does not make sense. If there is no `return`, you cannot read the return value (in C).