# Passing function parameters and no return statement

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int,int);

main()
{
      int a=2,b=3;
      printf("%d %d %d",a,b,add(a,b));
      getch();
}

int add(int a,int b)
{
     int c;
     c=a+b;     
}
```

Ok fine this gives me output `2 3 5` ..But for below program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int add(int,int);

main()
{
      int a=2,b=3;
      printf("%d %d %d",a,b,add(a,b));
      getch();
}

int add(int a,int b)
{
     int c;
     c=a+b;
     c=0;     
}
```

Still it is giving `2 3 5` as output.. as we have no `return` statement final statement `c=0` not initializing .. it should give `2 3 0` but it is giving `2 3 5` only.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr) explains it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very good question.

Inside  the function add ()
the expression

```
c=a+b;
```

is evaluated
In this expression the right hand side has to be evaluated first.
So it returns the value of a+b and that value is stored in your return register and that value is finally stored in c.

In the next expression

```
c=0;
```

It is just initialising the value of 0 to c.
It does not need to return any value.
So the value of the return register is still 5.

Comment: thank you very much .... now i am free of this doubt.. & thanks again Akshay

Answer (score 5):

It's undefined behavior, anything could happen, you can't rely on it.

Probably what happened is, in the function `add()`, the value of `c` is calculated, and left in the stack, in the `printf()` call, what's in that particular address of stack is printed. Again, you can't rely on undefined behavior.