# Character pointers messed up in simple Boyer-Moore implementation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently experimenting with a very simple Boyer-Moore variant.
In general my implementation works, but if I try to utilize it in a loop the character pointer containing the haystack gets messed up. And I mean that characters in it are altered, or mixed.
The result is consistent, i.e. running the same test multiple times yields the same screw up.

This is the looping code:

```
string src("This haystack contains a needle! needless to say that only 2 matches need to be found!");
string pat("needle");
const char* res = src.c_str();

while((res = boyerMoore(res, pat)))
    ++res;
```

This is my implementation of the string search algorithm (the above code calls a convenience wrapper which pulls the character pointer and length of the string):

```
unsigned char*
boyerMoore(const unsigned char* src, size_t srcLgth, const unsigned char* pat, size_t patLgth)
{
    if(srcLgth < patLgth || !src || !pat)
        return nullptr;

    size_t skip[UCHAR_MAX]; //this is the skip table
    for(int i = 0; i < UCHAR_MAX; ++i)
        skip[i] = patLgth; //initialize it with default value

    for(size_t i = 0; i < patLgth; ++i)
        skip[(int)pat[i]] = patLgth - i - 1; //set skip value of chars in pattern

    std::cout<<src<<"\n"; //just to see what's going on here!

    size_t srcI = patLgth - 1; //our first character to check
    while(srcI < srcLgth)
    {
        size_t j = 0; //char match ct
        while(j < patLgth)
        {
            if(src[srcI - j] == pat[patLgth - j - 1])
                ++j;
            else
            {
                //since the number of characters to skip may be negative, I just increment in that case

                size_t t = skip[(int)src[srcI - j]];
                if(t > j)
                    srcI = srcI + t - j;
                else
                    ++srcI;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == patLgth)
            return (unsigned char*)&src[srcI + 1 - j];
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

The loop produced this output (i.e. these are the haystacks the algorithm received):

1. This haystack contains a needle! needless to say that only 2 matches need to be found!
2. eedle! needless to say that only 2 matches need to be found!
3. eedless to say that eed  2 meed to beed to be found!

As you can see the input is completely messed up after the second run. What am I missing? I thought the contents could not be modified, since I'm passing `const` pointers.
Is the way of setting the pointer in the loop wrong, or is my string search screwing up?

Btw: This is the complete code, except for includes and the main function around the looping code.

**EDIT:**

The missing `nullptr` of the first return was due to a copy/paste error, in the source it is actually there.

For clarification, this is my wrapper function:

```
inline char* boyerMoore(const string &src, const string &pat)
{
    return (const char*) boyerMoore((const unsigned char*) src.c_str(), src.size(),
            (const unsigned char*) pat.c_str(), pat.size());
}
```

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ Stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: That "off-by-one" is not an error, that is because I'm incrementing the result once and then pass it to the function. The changing of `src` is what bugs me.

Comment: You are not changing src, you are chaning res. res is a pointer to a char*, and you incremented it (++res after the while).

Comment: Sorry, meant `res`...

Comment: There are several issues that prevent this from even compiling, but once I did compile it, it ran without the #3 error that you have.  You're passing 2 parameters to a function that takes 4 arguments, and you're mixing up char* and unsigned char*.  Also, the first return of your `boyerMoore()` isn't returning a value.  What compiler are you using for this?  I was using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: As mentioned, what I call is a convenience wrapper, which does the conversion to `unsigned char*` and provides the length. Though it is strange, that it didn't return a value for you. I'm using `gcc 4.9.2`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about the wrapper.  Your function above has a `return;`, and I think that needs to be `return nullptr;`  That could be the issue.  Also, I guess your wrapper is using something like `strlen(res)` because using the wrong length could also cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your `boyerMoore()` function, the first return isn't returning a value (you have just `return;` rather than `return nullptr;`)  GCC doesn't always warn about missing return values, and not returning anything is undefined behavior.  That means that when you store the return value in `res` and call the function again, there's no telling what will print out.  You can see a [related discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr).

Also, you have omitted your convenience function that calculates the length of the strings that you are passing in.  I would recommend double checking that logic to make sure the sizes are correct - I'm assuming you are using `strlen` or similar.

Comment: Since I'm using `std::string` in this case I'm relying on the `size()` member function. The missing return value was actually a copy/paste error, I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: In your added wrapper, you casting the return value as (const char*), but the function returns char*.  Thats not legal.  Also, what happened to unsigned char*?  I feel like there are details in your code that you are not posting that are causing issues.  The incomplete examples aren't helping.

Comment: Remove all your wrappers and make all your pointers agree.  Stop using `unsigned char*` unless there is a very compelling reason (tip: probably not).  The main boyerMoore function seems to work fine, so again I think the devil is in the details _that you aren't showing us_.