# Why does a function returning `int` in C++ compile even if I didn't include the return statement?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does a C++ function that returns a numeric value such as `int` or `double` work just fine if I don't include the return statement?
Should I avoid that even though the program runs fine? 
Thanks

Comment: How did you check that it works fine? And yes, you should avoid such as thing and you will get some warnings from the compiler.

Comment: I guess because it compiles and runs.

Comment: Your questions have already been answered : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr)

Answer (score 3):

It could "work fine" for two reasons:

1. Your function is not `main()`, in which case flowing off the end with no return statement causes *undefined behaviour*<sup>1</sup>, and it just happens that it seems to work fine. But it doesn't really.
2. The function is `main()`, which has an implicit `return 0;`.

For case 1, you should consider your code badly broken and fix it.

---

<sup>1 **§6.3.3 [stmt.return]** in the C++11 standard</sup>

Comment: Nice answer! Maybe also just worth adding a little note about how `main` can omit the return statement (just for completeness).

Comment: @Ike implicitly it is there, because return value of main isnt used

Comment: In C++, it's UB even if the return value is not used.

Comment: @Ike Good point. "Nobody expects the Spanish inquisition!"

Comment: @cpplearner Found it, 6.6.3.

Comment: "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function." _§6.3.3_