# Missing return statement and cppcheck

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I created a function

```
static int init_module(void)
{

}
```

Then ran CppCheck. It doesn't complain that there's no return statement, and it'd be reasonable if it complained.

Why?

Comment: which parameters did you use?

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no <br>