# why getting error missing return statment? (in java) and not in c++

Tags: java, c++, function, loops

I have created this function for my game that should read a string, something like "3 Spade" and return its worth (this example it is worth 3 points).

The problem is that I get this error: `no return statement found`

Although when I write the same exact C++ code it runs without any error (I am coming from C++ background)

The Java code:

```
public static int getCardValue(String card)
{
    for(int s=0; s != cardSuits.length; s++) //cardSuits is an array of strings 
        for(int r=0; r != cardRanks.length; r++)//cardRanks is an array of strings 
        {
            String GeneratedCard = cardRanks[r] + " " + cardSuits[s];
            if((GeneratedCard).equals(card))
                {
                    if(r >= 0 && r <= 8) //number in array starts from 0(2) to 8(10)
                    {
                        return r;
                    }
                    else if( r >= 8 && r <= 12) //from 8(10) to 11(KING)
                    {
                        return 10;
                    }
                }
            else
             return -1;
        }
}
```

The same exact C++ code (tested and verified on this specific case for this post)

```
int Game::func(std::string card)
{
    for (int s = 0; s != 3; s++) //cardSuits is an array of strings 
        for (int r = 0; r != 13; r++)//cardRanks is an array of strings 
        {
            std::string GeneratedCard = cardRanks[r] + " " + cardSuits[s];
            if (GeneratedCard==card)
            {
                if (r >= 0 && r <= 8) //number in array starts from 0(2) to 8(10)
                {
                    return r;
                }
                else if (r >= 8 && r <= 12) //from 8(10) to 11(KING)
                {
                    return 10;
                }
            }
            else
                return -1;
        }
}
```

I am interested in 2 things:

1. to know the working version of the java code
2. why is there this difference between the c++ and the java code

Comment: Because Java is not C++. And C++ is not Java.

Comment: if cardSuits.length = 0, then the compiler will not find a return satement.

Comment: As it stands now your question is too broad and/or unclear.

Comment: What do you return if `cardSuits` is empty? What do you return if `cardRanks` is empty? What do you return if `(GeneratedCard).equals(card)` is always *true*, but the inner `if` statements always *false*?

Comment: @RawN what should i do , to make it more specific?

Comment: This question basically comes down to why a certain standard says "A" while another says "B". The c++ standard clearly states *"**Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a cv void return type is equivalent to a return with no operand. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than main results in undefined behavior.**"* at [6.6.3/2]

Comment: @Eyad Read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve future inquires.

Comment: oh well, it looks like its just an implementation difference between the 2 languages.
as trying those extreme cases that java worries about --- in c++ it just returns 0 instead of complaining and not working at all...
thanks for every one answered me... it really helped

Comment: No in c++ it doesn't *"just returns 0 instead of complaining"*. The behavior is undefined. You shouldn't rely on anything specific happening.

Comment: And in Java, this is not an implementation detail.  The JLS requires that any way that a non-void method can return must be via an explicit `return` statement which supplies an explicit return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- JAVA getCardValue method is a return type function So you should handle the return value in each case even it was a FOR LOOP function as it depends on a condition

```
public static int getCardValue(String card) {
    for (int s = 0; s != cardSuits.length; s++){
        for (int r = 0; r != cardRanks.length; r++) {
            String GeneratedCard = cardRanks[r] + " " + cardSuits[s];
            if ((GeneratedCard).equals(card)) {
                if (r >= 0 && r <= 8)
                    return r;// handling if condition
                else if (r >= 8 && r <= 12)
                    return 10;// returning value else if condition
            }else{
                return 0;// returning value else condition
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;// returning value FOR loop condition
}
```

2- I think you should put these return values in C++ function too as it is a return type function

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Java is going through your if, else-if, and else statements and making sure that the method always returns a value.
So your code looks like this

```
if A
  if B
    return
  else if C
     return
else
  return
```

Therefore, Java can see that if you have a state which is A and not B and not C, there is a logical path that does not return a value.

You could resolve this by putting a default return at the end of the method.
Or you could throw an Exception if you think it is an unreachable state because there are only so many cards.

```
public static int getCardValue(String card)
{
  for (int s = 0; s != cardSuits.length; s++)
    // cardSuits is an array of strings
    for (int r = 0; r != cardRanks.length; r++)// cardRanks is an array of
                                               // strings
    {
      String GeneratedCard = cardRanks[r] + " " + cardSuits[s];
      if ((GeneratedCard).equals(card))
      {
        if (r >= 0 && r <= 8) // number in array starts from 0(2) to 8(10)
        {
          return r;
        }
        else if (r >= 8 && r <= 12) // from 8(10) to 11(KING)
        {
          return 10;
        }
      }
      else
        return -1;
    }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: While Java does branch analysis C++ does not, when a C++ function does not return with a return statement. It's return value is undefined, unless it is the main function in which case it returns 0.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no