# Understanding a recursive Binary Search Algorithm that mysteriously works

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, search, binary-search

On an assignment I had to make a recursive binary search algorithm output the index instead of True/False without modifying the parameters. I had a really tough time but after resorting to semi-trial-and-error I stumbled upon this mess:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;


int BinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {

    int temp = 0;
    int mid = len/2;

    if (len <= 0) return INT_MIN;  // not found
    if (target == arr[mid]){
        return mid; // found
    }

    if (target < arr[mid]){
        temp = BinarySearch(arr, mid, target);
    }

    else {
        temp = mid+1 + BinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target);              
    }
}
```

I have literally no idea why it works, even after running it through a visualizer. It's very sensitive to the code being changed and I can't get it to output -1 when it fails to find the target so I made it at least always output a negative number instead.

I don't really need it fixed, I just want to know how it even works since seemingly none of the recursive call's outputs are even used. Thanks.

Comment: Try to [explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Or step through it line by line (stepping into the recursive calls) with a debugger. Both ways are good to find a very big bug, that leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `INT_MIN` as a "not found" is kinda bad. It's a perfectly valid integer value.

Answer (score 5):

It is undefined behaviour (see e.g. [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)).

The compiler appears to return *temp* by chance, likely because it is the first local variable declared inside the function. Returning *temp* would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to return -1, if the target is not found and the index of the target otherwise. In

```
if (len <= 0) return INT_MIN;  // not found
```

you are returning `INT_MIN`, if the target is not found. You need to change it to

```
if (len <= 0) return -1;  // not found
```

Since your function returns an `int` value, it has to return something on each patch. You can fix it by adding the `return` at the end of the function:

```
    if (target < arr[mid]){
        temp = BinarySearch(arr, mid, target);
    }

    else {
        temp = mid+1 + BinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target);              
    }
    return temp;
}
```

`BinarySearch` returns the index of `target` in the current `arr`. Since the current `arr` often doesn't begin with index `0`, you're adding and subtracting `mid+1`. You're also doing it, if the target was not found and `BinarySearch` returns `-1`. You have to fix the `else` part:

```
else {
    int index(BinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target));
    temp = index == -1 ? -1 : mid + 1 + index;              
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, it was returning `temp` after all. The problem still persists with returning -1 if not found though. It seems to add whatever number I want to return in `if (len <= 0) return x;`, and I can't figure out a way to make it -1 each time (since `temp` contains the index, which changes).

Comment: I've found another mistake and edited my answer.

Comment: Ah ha! That works, thanks you. I don't understand what the line 

`int index(BinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target));` 

does though. Is it a function or just a way of declaring a variable I've never seen before?

Comment: It's the `c++` way of `int index = BinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target);`