# 12 days of Christmas C++ using functions

Tags: c++

I am in a beginner C++ course and I am trying to create a program that outputs the 12 days of Christmas song using the two given function calls show_ordinal(int) and show_verse(int) as an assignment. It is supposed to call the verse and show the day with it's ordinal suffix and then loop the remaining verses depending on where the user decides to start from, so if it was show_verse(3) it would be on the 3rd day of Christmas... all the way to the pear tree. I started writing for the function to get the ordinal but kept getting segmentation fault errors.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string show_ordinal(int);
void show_verse(int);

int main()
{
    cout << show_ordinal(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}

string show_ordinal(int x)
{
    switch (x % 10)
    {

        case 1:
            if (x % 10 == 1)
            {
                cout << x << "st";
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (x % 10 == 2)
            {
                cout << x << "nd";
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if (x % 10 == 3)
            {
                cout << x << "rd";
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            if (x % 10 != 1 || x % 10 != 2 || x % 10 != 3)
            {
                cout << x << "th";
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Testing the function by trying to call it with an int value of 2 in main,I have been working on it for awhile and cannot get it to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because you somehow copied line number with it.

Comment: Unrelated warning. You use `string` without `#include <string>`. This is unreliable. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't work. Don't count on other headers to include stuff you need.

Answer (score 1):

`show_ordinal` returns nothing for

```
cout << show_ordinal(2) << endl;
```

to print out. It promises to return a `string`, but it never does. This is bad form. When a function has a non-`void` return type it must return a result on *all* code paths or the function, and the program, is ill formed. A crash or other segfault is a common result, but you could get silent corruption of data, and that is much harder to track down.

Rather than `cout`ing all of your results, assign the results to a `string` and return the `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You never return a string from show_ordinal(), you just output to `cout`.  Instead of using `cout`, I think you want to contsruct a string using `x` and your computed suffix and return that:

```
string show_ordinal(int x) {
    string out;

    switch (x % 10) {
        case 1:
            out = to_string(x) + "st";
            break;
        case 2:
            out = to_string(x) + "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
            out = to_string(x) + "rd";
            break;
        default:
            out = to_string(x) + "th";
            break;
    }

    return  out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably count yourself lucky that you experienced a seg fault, because what you are doing is producing undefined behavior.  If you don't believe me, check out [what OnlineGDB does to your code](https://onlinegdb.com/BJAtR2hdf).

The problem is that you define `show_ordinal` with a return value of `std::string`, but never return anything from the function.  [This produces undefined behavior in the C++ specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610454/5075720).  To fix it you can do one of these two things:

**Actually return a string**.  Rather than shifting into `std::cout` within the function, shift into an `std::ostringstream` instead, then return the stringified version:

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

std::string show_ordinal(int x) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    switch (x % 10) {

    case 1:
        // Note:  I got rid of your extraneous "if" statement.
        // "switch" is already doing that work for you.
        oss << x << "st";
        break;

    /* more cases here */

    }

    return oss.str();
}
```

**Define the function to return nothing**.  If you really want the function to handle the shifting to `std::cout`, define it with a `void` return signature and don't shift the output to `std::cout` in `main`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

void show_ordinal(int x);

int main() {
    show_ordinal(2);
}

void show_ordinal(int x) {
    switch (x % 10) {

    case 1:
        std::cout << x << "st\n";
        break;

    /* more cases here */

    }
}
```

Either of these should solve your problem.

**Note:**  A few more things:

1. Please include all the headers for the standard libraries you are using.  Add `#include<string>`.
2. You don't need those extra `if` statements in the `case` blocks.  If your code made it to `case 1`, then `x % 10 == 1` is guaranteed, so don't check it again.
3. `show_ordinal` won't do anything for `x % 10 > 4`.  Consider replacing `case 4` with `default`.  See the [documentation for the `switch` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).
4. Please [get out of the habit of `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5075720).  It will get you in trouble in the future.