# no-return lambda strange behavior

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, return, c++14

I just find something that couldn't understand. I think it should be related to the functions stack and some undefined behavior.

Let's say I have a function factory template (silly one):

```
template <unsigned int N=10>
std::function<int&&(const int& n)> build_add_function() {
    return [](const int& n) -> int&& {std::move(n+N);};
}
```

As you can see, it lacks the return statement on a non-void function, hence the compiler throw me a warning...
The strange thing is that it works **"as expected"**

```
int main() {
  auto foo = build_add_function();
  std::cout << foo(10);
}
```

main output: **`20`**

Of course, to fix the code, I added the `return` statement and it gives me a segmentation fault

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I have some misconception of what I'm doing for sure, but I just can not get it around. Would someone explain to me what is happening here?
I'm using `gcc` version `8.0.1`

EDIT: Just tested on `gcc 4.8.1` and worked as expected with the return statement and no compilation errors.

Is it a compiler stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the cases are undefined behavior.

The behavior of non-void function lacks `return` statement is [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610030/3309790) (except for `main()`), that means anything is possible. Even you might get the "correct" result you shouldn't rely on it.

When you added the `return` statement like `return std::move(n+N);`, you're trying to return a reference to temporary, which is always dangled, and dereference on it leads to UB too.

Comment: the idea is that im marking the variable to be moved instead of copied, so the fix is just to use copy instead?

Comment: so, would this work if it were for a custom class for example? or how to fix it then?

Comment: @Netwave Sorry I was wrong. It has nothing to do with built-in types. Note that `std::move` doesn't perform move operation, it just converts the operand to rvalue. (BTW `std::move` is redundant in fact, `n+N` is already an rvalue.) So all what the lambda do is binding a temporary to the rvalue-reference and return it. The temporary is destroyed imediately, so the returned reference is always dangled. Change the return type to `int` would be fine.

Comment: actually move may be redundant, but that is not the problem, the problem is that the compiler is complaining about using `move` directly on the operation without an intermediate storing variable.

Comment: @Netwave You meant the compiler is complaining about `std::move(n+N)`?

Comment: yes, exactly that, adding one more line make him understand

Comment: @Netwave I think it complains because `n+N` is already an rvalue, using `std::move` is redundant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178188/discussion-between-netwave-and-songyuanyao).