# Confusion about Copy Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, copy-constructor

**Code:**

```
class A 
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"Defualt Constructor"<<endl;
    }

    A(A &t) 
    { 
        cout<<"Copy Constructor"<<endl;
    }
};

A func()
{
    cout<<"In func"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2;
    a2 = func();
    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine. Also, If I call function like this:

```
A a2 = func();
```

and add `const` qualifier in **copy** **constructor** argument like:

```
A(const A &t) 
{ 
    cout<<"Copy Constructor"<<endl;
}
```

Also, working fine.

But, If remove `const` from **copy constructor** argument like:

```
A(A &t) 
{ 
   cout<<"Copy Constructor"<<endl;
}
```

and call function `func()`

```
A a2 = func();
```

Compiler giving an error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'
      A a2 = func();
                 ^
prog.cpp:13:9: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'A::A(A&)'
         A(A &t) 
         ^
```

Why does compiler give an error in last case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A a2 = func();` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), `a2` will be initialized from the object returned by `func()` via copy constructor. `func()` returns by value, so what it returns is a temporary, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const (i.e. `A &`), that's why you get the error.

Temporary could be bound to lvalue-reference to `const` (or rvalue-reference), so changing the parameter type to `const A &t` (or adding move constructor) would make it work fine.

BTW: `a2 = func();` has nothing to do with copy constructor, but copy assignment operator. You didn't declare it for `A`, and the [implicitly declared copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) takes `const A&` as parameter, then it's fine.

BTW2: `func()` returns nothing. Note that [flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610030/3309790) leads to UB.

Comment: Since `func()` doesn't have a return statement, isn't `A a2 = func();` invoking UB? What I'm missing here?

Comment: @taskinoor Yes it is UB.