# Why does this Lambda compiles?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Do()
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

int Call(int(*f)())
{
    return f();
}

int main()
{
    // WHY DOES THE FOLLOWING COMPILE???!!! 
    // NOTE THE MISSING RETURN STATEMENT
    Call([]()->int{ Do(); });
}
```

It seems for some compiler, the code above compiles fine, and it also works. But apparently, the lambda is missing the return statement. Why does this work? Is it a problem with the compiler? What does the lambda return in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It has more to do with how a function returning an integer is allowed to not have a return statement. This doesn't really have much to do with lambda.

See the following on this topic: [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expression returns closure with defined call function operator as body of lambda. In your case this call function operator returns `int`, so it may look like:

```
class unnamedClass {
  int operator()() const
  {
    Do();
  } // return is missing here
};
```

and it is undefined behaviour according to [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return).

> Flowing off the end of a value-returning function (except main)
>   without a return statement is undefined behavior.

Compiler compiles it, but it leads to UB. On g++ i got warning `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`.

So if you want your code to work correctly, you need add `return`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I wonder why it is a warning instead of a compile error. In what case would the warning be preferred over a compile error? Do you know why this is done this way? I ran into this situation as a bug, so I want to see if there is anything to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no

Comment: It leads to UB *if* `Do();` returns normally (instead of e.g. throwing).