# Unexpected behavior of g++-8 g++-9 -O2 optimization

Tags: linux, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
__attribute__((optimize("O2"))) static void* verify(char *str)
{
  if (str[0] == 0)
  {
    puts("MM");
    exit(-2);
  }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  verify(argv[0]);
  puts("GG");
  return 1;
}
```

Here is my code. When I compile it using `g++8/g++9/clang++-6/clang++-8`  with `-O2` optimization, the program prints "MM" instead of "GG". I know return statement is missing in function `verify`, but I never use the return
value. Is there any explanation?

By the way, my test environment is `ubuntu 1804` and `g++-7` generates correct program.

Comment: If you define your function as returning a value, but don't actually return anything from it, and call the function, undefined behavior means all bets are off. Fix your function and see if it still happens.

Comment: @Shawn adding a _return_ GG is written using gcc 8.1.0

Comment: Is it really an undefined behavior when I omit return statement?  I think using return value is undefined behavior, but missing return statement not to be.

Comment: This may be a case where a C tag vs a C++ tag is important...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610030/1918193

Comment: Oh, Great link. C++ has different behavior