# Unexpected behavior when passing const string to function c++

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

I'm getting an unexpected behavior when passing a `const string` to a function as a parameter.

I have this function:

```
std::string getStatusByTopic(const std::string topic){
    if (topic.compare(TOPIC_WP_SM_CMD) == 0)
            return state_to_string(STATUSES::WP_HANDLER_STATUS);
}
```

*Which is not totally implemented yet.*

And I have this function:

```
InsertStatus(getStatusByTopic(TOPIC_WP_SM_CMD),msg);
```

Which declared as:

```
void Msp::InsertStatus(const std::string status_topic, const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& new_status)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. These functions have been compiled successfully, even though there's a possible usage where `getStatusByTopic()` returns nothing when its defined returned type is **string**. How is it possible?
2. When the code is executed, with the scenario that and `getStatusByTopic(TOPIC_WP_SM_CMD)` returns nothing. There's no runtime errors, more over - **TOPIC_WP_SM_CMD** is passed as parameter to `InsertStatus()` (which is defined ad "/some/topic/"). How is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a) Undefined Behaviour is undefined. It can do whatever it wants. To catch such errors, [enable your compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: What options did you pass to your compiler? In particular, have you enabled all the available warnings (you should). Your compiler should be able to inform you about this example of UB.

Comment: Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)