# freeing memory causing segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, binary-search-tree, free

I'm trying to create a binary search tree. This is my node initialization function:

```
node_t* node_init(int val){
        node_t* n1 = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        n1->value = val;
        n1->leftNode = NULL;
        n1->rightNode = NULL;

        return n1;
}
```

Since I'm malloc'ing memory, I know I should be freeing it somewhere else. I do so in my main method:

```
int main(){
        tree_t t1;
        tree_init(&t1);
        
        node_t* n1 = node_init(5);

        node_t* n2 = node_init(7);
        

        t1.count += add(n1, &(t1.root));
        t1.count += add(n2, &(t1.root));

        //free(n1);
        //free(n2);
        
        print_tree(t1.root);
}
```

Yet, when I uncomment the freeing lines, I get a segmentation fault error. I'm not sure why that Is the case since I must free the memory once it's been allocated. I don't do any freeing in my `add` function, and the code prints out a valid binary search tree without the `free` statements.

If it helps, here is my add function:

```
int add(node_t* n, node_t** tn){
        if(*tn == NULL){*tn = n; return 1;}
        if(n->value < (*tn)->value){add(n, &((*tn)->leftNode));}
        else if (n->value > (*tn)->value){add(n, &((*tn)->rightNode));}
        else{return 0;}
}
```

Comment: If possible, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Once you free the nodes, you may not access them again.  It seems reasonable to think that `print_tree` would attempt to access the nodes in the tree, so you must not free them before calling that function.

Comment: Typically, one would free all the nodes in the tree by traversing the tree to find them, not by retaining and using separate pointers to them.  Either way can work, but the latter requires maintaining extra data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the function add has undefined behavior because in some paths of execution it returns nothing.

You need to write

```
int add(node_t* n, node_t** tn){
        if(*tn == NULL){*tn = n; return 1;}
        if(n->value < (*tn)->value){ return add(n, &((*tn)->leftNode));}
        else if (n->value > (*tn)->value){ return add(n, &((*tn)->rightNode));}
        else{return 0;}
}
```

These statements with calls of free

```
    free(n1);
    free(n2);
```

do not set n1 and n2 to NULL in the tree. So this call

```
    print_tree(t1.root);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Understood! Sorry, you said the free calls "do not set n1 and n2 to NULL in the tree?" So what are they set to, and why does printing the tree invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: @rjc810 The function free just frees the memory pointed to by the pointer used as an argument.. The original pointer itself used as an argument is not changed.  So in the function print_tree you are using the pointers n1 and n2 to access memory that was already freed.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"the function add has undefined behavior because in some paths of execution it returns nothing."`  -- This statement is not quite correct. In contrast to C++, this does not cause undefined behavior in C. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610030/12149471) for further information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel There is used the return value of the function like t1.count += add(n1, &(t1.root));

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, accessing the non-existant return value is what causes the undefined behavior in C. Therefore, the undefined behavior is not caused by the function `add`, but rather by the function `main`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It seems you do not understand the answer in the provided by you reference. There is written that in such a case except main there is undefined behavior. "This code has formally undefined behaviour"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What do you mean by "the answer"? The question I linked to has 9 answers. Do you mean the accepted answer? That answer talks mainly about C++, and only mentions that the situation is different in C, without stating in what way it is different.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: [§6.9.1 ¶12 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12) clearly states that what I said is correct, namely that the undefined behavior is not invoked by the function `add` not returning a value, but rather by the function `main` accessing the non-existant return value. Note that this question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel This quote does not mean that if a function has a non-void return type and returns nothing then the behavior of the function is defined. If a function has a non-void return type then its return statements shall return an expression.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, you are right that according to [§6.8.6.4 ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.4p1), if there is an explicit `return` statement, then it must contain a return value. However, this does not apply if there is no explicit return statement, but instead the `}` which terminates the function is reached. In that case, [§6.9.1 ¶12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12) applies.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  I have not found in the Standard how the behavior of a function is defined that does not return explicitly something though having a non-void return type.