# What is the Visual Studio warning equivalent of GCC's -Wreturn-type?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

Does Visual Studio have a warning (or warnings) that is the equivalent of GCC's [-Wreturn-type](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wreturn-type)?

More specifically, I am looking for a Visual Studio warning (or warnings) that will warn for instances in functions whose return types are not `void` where

1. There is a `return` statement with no return value; or
2. It is possible function execution could "fall off" the end of the function body without returning a value

I am not concerned with the other part of `-Wreturn-type` that warns whenever a function is defined with a return type that defaults to `int`.

<sub>*For reference, the GCC warning options can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).*</sub>

Comment: [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4033](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4033)

Comment: And [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4716](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4716).

Comment: These warnings do not cover the "fall off" case I demonstrate in the test 3's above.

Comment: If you want to find out whether a warning that you want exists, just enable all and test against a small piece of code. If there is a warning, congrats, you found it. If not, tough luck, there isn't any.

Comment: Got [C4715](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4715?view=msvc-170) in test three if all warnings are enabled. Are there any missing cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this can be done with [C4033](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4033), [C4716](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4716), [C4715](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4715).

User [n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m) also makes a very good point about how to find [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) warnings in general:

> If you want to find out whether a warning that you want exists, just enable all [using `/Wall`] and test against a small piece of code. If there is a warning, congrats, you found it. If not, tough luck, there isn't any.

I tested both with `.c` and `.cpp` file extensions, just in case the compiler behaved differently based on the language it is compiling (and sure enough, the behaviour was different for test 2).

None of my tests ever complain about `main()`, because `main()` is special, as it is the only function in C and C++ that defaults to returning `0` if no explicit `return` is provided.

All of the tests below were done using Visual Studio 2015's compiler (i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe`), and the commands were issued from the VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt.

If I am missing any test cases, please leave a comment to let me know.

### Tests

#### C tests

**Test 1 - Empty function with `int` return type**

test_warnings.c:

```
int main() {}

int foo() {}
```

Compile results:

```
>cl /nologo /W0 /we4033 /we4716 /we4715 C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.c
test_warnings.c
c:\users\administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.c(3) : error C4716: 'foo': must return a value
```

**Test 2 - Function with `int` return type with a `return` without a value**

test_warnings.c:

```
int main() {}

int foo() {
    return;
}
```

Compile results:

```
>cl /nologo /W0 /we4033 /we4716 /we4715 C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.c
test_warnings.c
C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.c(4): error C4033: 'foo' must return a value
```

**Test 3 - Function with `int` return type where execution could "fall off"  the end of the function**

This test demonstrates that these warnings are not enough, as there is no warning or error emitted for this code.

test_warnings.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {}

int foo() {
    int rand_num;
    srand(time(0));
    rand_num = rand();

    if (rand_num > 1) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compile results:

```
>cl /nologo /W0 /we4033 /we4716 /we4715 C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.c
test_warnings.c
c:\users\administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.c(14) : error C4715: 'foo': not all control paths return a value
```

#### C++ tests

**Test 1 - Empty function with `int` return type**

test_warnings.cpp:

```
int main() {}

int foo() {}
```

Compile results:

```
>cl /nologo /W0 /we4033 /we4716 /we4715 C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp
test_warnings.cpp
c:\users\administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp(3) : error C4716: 'foo': must return a value
```

**Test 2 - Function with `int` return type with a `return` without a value**

test_warnings.cpp:

```
int main() {}

int foo() {
    return;
}
```

Compile results:

```
>cl /nologo /W0 /we4033 /we4716 /we4715 C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp
test_warnings.cpp
C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp(4): error C2561: 'foo': function must return a value
C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp(3): note: see declaration of 'foo'
```

**Test 3 - Function with `int` return type where execution could "fall off"  the end of the function**

test_warnings.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {}

int foo() {
    int rand_num;
    srand(time(0));
    rand_num = rand();

    if (rand_num > 1) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compile results:

```
>cl /nologo /W0 /we4033 /we4716 /we4715 C:\Users\Administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp
test_warnings.cpp
c:\users\administrator\src\test-code\test_warnings.cpp(14) : error C4715: 'foo': not all control paths return a value
```

### Can you get this with just C4715?

I reran my tests above to see if you can get the same behaviour with just C4715, and here are my results. The command I used for testing this was

```
cl /nologo /W0 /we4715 <path to file>
```

| Test | C | C++ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test 1 | No warning or error | Triggers C4716 as an error, even though this is not turned on (which makes sense, as the [docs for this warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4716) say it is automatically promoted to error unless [`#pragma warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170) is used to prevent this) |
| Test 2 | No warning or error | Triggers [C2561](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2561) (a compiler error) |
| Test 3 | Triggers C4715 | Triggers C4715 |

This means C4715 is sufficient for C++, but not sufficient for C.

### Notes

C4715 may warn if you call a function that never returns. For example, if you call a function that ends with `while (true) {}` or `throw "error message";`. To avoid this, declare the function that never returns with [`__declspec(noreturn)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noreturn?view=msvc-170), or if you are using C++11 or newer, you can use the more portable [`[[noreturn]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn) in the function declaration. (If you are calling a standard library function like [`exit()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/), the compiler will not issue a warning because it will know that function never returns.)

For some interesting related discussion, see [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no).