# Visual studio failing to compile function which takes input from user and puts it into array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int input(int arr[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value #" << (i + 1) << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
}

int main() {

    int x[3], y[3];
    input(x);
    input(y);


    cout << x[0];
}
```

Simple code to test if "input" function works correctly, but failing to compile in Visual Studio with the pop-up message "There were build errors".

When commenting out "int main", the same error is presented so I have to assume the issue is with the function. Online compilers like Programiz can run this same code just fine. When program works correctly it just outputs the first value entered by user.

Comment: What are the actual compiler errors? Look in the output window. Does `input` return an `int`?

Comment: error C4716: 'input': must return a value.

Comment: So if you read that error message and look at your function do you see the problem?

Comment: I feel like an idiot now, but yes I do! I managed to fix it, thanks for the help.

Comment: Change `int input(int arr[3]) {` to `void input(int arr[3]) {` it doesn't look like the input function needs to return an `int`

Comment: [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)

Comment: Incidentally, `int arr[3]` as a function argument means exactly the same thing as `int arr[]` and as `int *arr`. The 3 is ignored, and the argument is passes as a pointer.