# Not returning from a function is not an error?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

What's the reasoning that for most major compilers, gcc, clang, nvc  produce only a warning while compiling following code (suppressable one).

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() { return 42; }   
int boo() { foo(); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << boo() << std::endl;
}
```

We just had incidents that barely didn't end in a human life losses by pure luck because that and such code was a part of hardware vendor code (an autopilot to be precise) which we couldn't change. The particular compiler didn't even produce a warning (only in such case when there is only a return in function). The original's reasoning  that `{foo();}` is an expression doesn't make sense, but I have hard time explain it to overseers.

More strange, in other cases compilers produce errors if there is nor eturn. Only compiler that diagnoses a error in this case is MSVC (practically any version).

Comment: Because requiring the compiler to enforce that a function always returns == solving halting problem. So heuristics generating warnings is the best we can get. Of course it could e.g. throw exception or call `std::terminate` instead of triggerring undefined behaviour but that is a separate issue.

Comment: @Quimby And yet, most modern statically-typed languages somehow do that. No UB in Java world...

Comment: @Quimby it's excarbated by fact that in some ABIs `int boo() { foo(); }` and `int boo() { return foo(); }` may actually work without full-program optimization, which leads, well, to problems. We found ourselves in inpasse because vendor claims that code is legal. Oddly enough if there is an `if()` in there, it's an error.

Comment: Consider changing the compiler settings to treat warnings as errors (very important for code where human safety is an issue). This also shows you why ALL of your code should compile without warnings.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it supresses warning in "system" headers. I think vendor compiler did too, it's based off gcc.

Comment: Ouch, seems some process changes are in order

Comment: `that barely didn't end in a human life`  You should then consider MISRA rule 17.4 from 2012 and AUTOSAR . Safety standards exists for a reason. The code you presented has undefined behavior. Compiler has no _requirement_ to issue an error on undefined behavior. Using function return value that does not have a return is undefined behavior. The act of not returning by itself is fine. Only when you attemptsto use the return value of non-returning function, then it becomes undefined.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sadly wrong authority. There is no safety standard regulating that here,except  regulating outcomes.  non-void function return. Yeah, OUR code follows that (and simply by test-compiling by compiler that does that). THe problem was a vendor library (MAVIK-related) and that header contained somethign like `getX()` functions with missing returns. Not our code. In debug builds that even worked as intended.

Comment: It may work in debug builds, most probably becuase `return 42` from `foo()` populates the return registers, which are then read by `main()`. In optimized build, the compiler will optimize the hell out of it, deduce that `return 42` is unused and optimize it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler needs to consider everything.

Small change:

```
int foo() { throw 42; }   
int boo() { foo(); }
```

Unusual, but entirely legal. There's no "missing return statement" in `foo`, but you need to know that `foo` always throws.

The idea isn't entirely far-fetched. If `foo` was called `log_and_throw<Exc>`, you'd expect it to never return normally.

Comment: I would  have thouht that [[noreturn]] exists for such cases.. or if it wouldn't be legal with no exception support (or case) but .. well..  this "not considering" just barely costed  lives of a few thousands and one who wrote is bulletproof thanks to this wording.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: In industries where that *really* is the case, you grab something like MISRA and slap the vendor with that. Rule violations are much, much worse than compiler warnings.

Comment: I totally agree, although as we had no losses and it was test  environment (we dropped it on ourselves) while MISRA has no legal weighthere, they'll go scots-free.

Comment: `int foo() { int x; std::cin >> x; if ( x == 42) throw 42; }` with this `foo` it is impossible for the compiler to know if calling `boo` is ok.

Comment: I'd say it's a quality of implementation issue. As @Swift-FridayPie points out, we do have `[[noreturn]]` -- given this, it seems reasonable for a compiler to warn if the function is not `[[noreturn]]` and doesn't have a `return`; `[[noreturn]]` makes it easy to turn the warning off.

Answer (score 4):

> Not returning from a function is not an error?

Accessing an array out of bounds is not a compilation error, signed overflow is also not a compilation error, `fflush(stdin)` is also not a compilation error. The compiler is not *required* to error on undefined behavior in your code. Undefined behavior means there are *no requirements* - compiler *can* error, may not, or may spawn nasal demons.

In C++, flowing to the end of non-void function is undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610454/9072753 and online draft https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.return-4 .

Comment: +1 for quote. Personally I would say they should learn to program instead of shotgunning it. Ihave a reputation of waving with "weird papers" at everyone,they they simply are unable to read them. These answerswould be  a "layman term"  thing I can add to my own "opinion" as they call it.

Comment: Both of those links are about C. The question is about C++

Comment: Och, that makes that paragarph not valid. Edited

Comment: I think this is a tiny bit wrong. I think the idea of "X is not a compilation error" here is that "a conforming C++ implementation is allowed but not required to emit a diagnostic". If the runtime behavior is **unavoidable**, then the implementation may additionally refuse to compile the code. But this gets us back to the first comment, proving if code is reachable is trivially equivalent to the halting problem.