# Why does the output change each time?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Could someone explain to me why result differs each time I execute this code.
If I add the `endl` statment in each `cout` I don't get the same output in the case of not using them?

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
#define MAX_NUM 30
#define MAX_SIZE 100
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
int sem_init ( sem_t * sem , int pshared , unsigned int value );
int sem_destroy ( sem_t * sem );
int sem_wait ( sem_t * sem );
int sem_post ( sem_t * sem );
sem_t Tab[6];

void *S1(void*)
{
    cout<<"helloS1"<<endl;
    sem_post(&Tab[0]);
    sem_post(&Tab[1]);
    sem_post(&Tab[2]);
}

void *S2(void*)
{
    sem_wait(&Tab[0]);
    cout<<"helloS2"<<endl;
    sem_post(&Tab[3]);
}

void *S3(void*)
{
    sem_wait(&Tab[1]);
    cout<<"helloS3"<<endl;
    sem_post(&Tab[3]);
}

void* S4(void*)
{
    sem_wait(&Tab[2]);
    cout<<"helloS4"<<endl;
    sem_post(&Tab[3]);
}

void* S5(void*)
{
    sem_wait(&Tab[3]);
    //sem_wait(&Tab[3]);
    //sem_wait(&Tab[3]);
    cout<<"helloS5";
}

void S6()
{
    cout<<"helloS6";
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        sem_init(&Tab[i],0,0);
    }
    pthread_t thread0,thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4;
    pthread_create(&thread0,NULL,S2,nullptr);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,S3,nullptr);
    pthread_create(&thread3,NULL,S4,nullptr);
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,S1,nullptr);
    
    pthread_join(thread0,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    //pthread_create(&thread4,NULL,S5,nullptr);
    //pthread_join(thread4,NULL);

    
    //S3(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that the expected result would be:

```
helloS1
helloS2
helloS3
helloS4
```

However I get randomly either:

```
helloS1
helloS3
or helloS1
helloS3
```

Comment: To form a code block type ``` press enter then paste the code as it is in your IDE. Press enter again. Then finally type ``` and press enter.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `std::thread` and change `<stdlib.h>` to `<cstdlib>` etc. Also see [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)

Comment: functions declared to return `void*` but not returning anything invoke undefined behavior when called

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai but isn't this how you are supposed to delcare them and become able to use pthread_create?If i don't the compiler would throw an error

Comment: yes this is how you are supposed to declare them. And you are supposed to return a `void*`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai so my mistake is not returning a nullpointer ?

Comment: i am not sure if this explains the wrong output. But with that mistake the code can result in any output.

Comment: The function is required to return `void *`.   That doesn't mean the function definition is allowed to simply "fall of the end"  (i.e.  to return to the caller with anything other than `return some_valid_pointer;`).   Falling off the end of the function causes undefined behaviour.  Two characteristics of undefined behaviour are (1) no diagnostic is required (a compiler is *permitted* to give an error message, but is still correct if it doesn't)   and  (2)  the behaviour produced by executing the code can be anything, whether that makes sense to the programmer or not.

Comment: fwiw a missing return does not invoke undefined behavior in C as long as you arent using the return value. In C++ it is undefined even if you do not use it. And still they keep saying it would be the same languages

Comment: @Peter thanks a lot it mostly resolved my problem but out of curiosity ,the order in which the hello are printed changing is due to the scheduler ?,i mean the algorithm that chooses which instruction is executed

Comment: thank all of you guys for the help ,now how do i mark this thread as completed ?

Comment: if you create 4 threads then any of them can come first, if you'd care about doing things in defined order you wouldn't use separate threads ;). Yes the scheduler.

Comment: Well, yeah.  The order of output is changed because of the scheduler.  When you create multiple threads, the scheduler is explicitly permitted to execute them, or interleave their execution, in any way it likes, unless the threads deliberately synchronise (e.g. cooperatively use a mutex).   The reason things change is that the scheduler monitors the whole system (background processes, other user processes, etc etc) and schedules things accordingly - that's its job.